# Moderation Strike update: Data dumps, choosing representatives, GPT data, and where we’re holding

Tags: discussion, moderation, stack-exchange, community, moderation-strike

<sub>Note: As part of the strike organization, this is a mirror of [a post on the network-wide Meta, MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390106). Make sure to check out the answers and discussion there, too!</sub>

#### Introduction

Since [our strike announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389811), a number of new developments have occurred. Philippe, VP of Community, [posted data they have regarding GPT content on the platform](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389928). Stack Exchange staff reached out to strike organizers and asked us to choose three moderator representatives for the strike. Also, a former DBA for Stack Exchange, Inc. [disclosed that data dumps have been disabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390023). This post strives to speak on these developments from the perspective of strike participants.

#### Strike representatives

We have been coordinating action on [our Discord server](https://discord.gg/B96X6DvvvT), as Stack Exchange, Inc. has instructed us in no uncertain terms that we cannot organize on their platform. Through this server, we were reached out to by employees of Stack Exchange, Inc. to designate representatives for the strike. These representatives will later meet with Stack Exchange, Inc. representatives and will negotiate on our behalf. These representatives must be moderators, as requested by the company, because some of the discussion points will involve information that is currently confidential and covered by the moderator agreement. Additionally, new data may be disclosed by SE that may not be cleared for public release, and must be protected for privacy reasons.

In order to decide the representatives, a poll was organised which ended at midnight UTC on the 11th of June. As a result of that poll, the following users will be representing us in discussions with Stack Exchange, Inc.:

[image]  [image]  [image]

The full, anonymized results of the voting can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7Kyp.png).

#### The Data Dumps

A former database administrator (DBA) for the company has disclosed that [Stack Exchange, Inc. quietly disabled the data dumps in March 2023](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390023), with a note that they should only be re-enabled with approval from senior leadership. Shortly after, [the CTO, Jody Bailey, confirmed this to be the case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390040), citing the need to “protect Stack Overflow data from being misused by companies building LLMs” and the dump has been stopped until “guardrails” are in place.

The Stack Exchange data dumps have been [in place since 2009](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/04/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/) and have been used to make network data available in an alternative format that allows people to take advantage of the open CC BY-SA license.

Disabling the data dumps in this manner is yet another example of poor communication with the very community of contributors who is at the heart of the network. The data dumps were turned off for several months, with no advance warning or communication until a user asked about it. And, even then, the company's decision was only revealed by a whistleblower, who effectively forced the CTO's hand to confirm it.

Perhaps more importantly, the data dumps serve to emphasize the very reason for the existence of the platform: **Guaranteed, free access to a repository of knowledge.** The network was founded to be an alternative to a paywalled platform and to guarantee that information was freely distributed. The data dumps were an insurance that no matter what happened with the company in the future, the information shared on the platform would always be freely accessible to all. Disabling these dumps is a betrayal of the founding philosophy of the network.

It would be hard to put it better than one of the site's founders, Joel Spolsky, did, when speaking on the [Stack Overflow podcast #84](https://dev.to/stackpodcast/podcast-84):

> We created Stack Overflow to be against [expropriation of community content]. If there's anything that's more in the DNA of Stack Overflow than that, I don't know what it is. That's one of our most core things. You can see this all over the place in the design of Stack Overflow.
>
> First of all, from day one, we use the CC-wiki license. And it's basically a license, it says that we don't own the content that's on there, which is why we make those database dumps that are available.
>
> Because we wanted to make sure that if no matter what happens, literally no matter who we sell to, or raise money from, or turn the site over to, and even if they take Stack Overflow, and make it an evil site where you have to pay to look at things and there's pop-up ads and pop-under ads, and you know, dancing chariots of fire that cross the screen and punch the monkey, and, man, I can take so many evil things anyway. And it just becomes a big gigantic spam site.
>
> Doesn't matter because just take the latest CC-wiki download that we provided and go start your own site saying, you know what, this is gonna be the clean version. And I think a lot of people will follow you. We very, very deliberately built Stack Overflow in a way that there wouldn't be any chance of locking and we're pretty much doing the same thing with Stack Exchange.

Beyond promoting openness, in the spirit of the CC BY-SA license, and serving as the final bulwark of the community and its contributors against a company that ever turns "evil", the data dumps were also key to innovative uses of Stack Overflow's knowledge base in environments like prisons and Arctic research labs, where no Internet connection is available to access the live site. You can read more about these initiatives, called the "Overflow Offline" Project, [on the Stack Overflow Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/10/20/introducing-the-overflow-offline-project/) and in [a *Verge* article by Mitchell Clark](https://www.theverge.com/2022/10/20/23413615/stack-overflow-offline-coding-copy-kiwix-prison-arctic).

#### The impact so far

Stack Exchange, Inc. has claimed in a [statement to the press](https://www.vice.com/en/article/4a33dj/stack-overflow-moderators-are-striking-to-stop-garbage-ai-content-from-flooding-the-site) that 11% of Stack Exchange moderators are participating in this strike. We would like to clarify that, while this was technically an accurate statement at the time that it was made, it was, even then, a misrepresentation of the actual percentage of moderator workload that had gone on strike (the moderators and flaggers who had gone on strike and suspended their activity were drawn disproportionately from those who were actively raising and handling flags). Therefore, this cited number failed to put the strike's effects into their proper perspective.

On Monday, June 5th, the notice about the strike was posted to Meta Stack Exchange, and the strike kicked into effect. The open letter, however, had been available to sign beforehand, as organization and coordination required. Some moderators signed the letter before it went "live" on June 5th (although their signatures publicly display as the 5th due to the strike not starting before then). The 11% of moderators cited is the percentage of moderators who had signed the letter *before it even went live*.

Currently, the vast majority of moderators on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) have suspended their activity. The pending flag queue has grown from just over 130 pending flags prior to Stack Exchange posting the moderator-private version of the AI generated content policy to an excess of 3,000, even while many of the most active flag-raising users have also ceased raising flags.

On multiple other sites (Super User, Software Engineering, Math, Academia, etc.) the majority of—or all—site moderators are on strike.

As of the time of writing, 113 out of 538 total Stack Exchange network moderators have signed the [open strike letter](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/), a percentage of 21%, and this number continues to grow.

#### The GPT data analysis

Stack Exchange, Inc. has [released some of the data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389928) behind their decision to override community consensus and prohibit moderators from handling AI-generated content. This data analysis has several flaws and unverifiable underlying assumptions, which have been examined in detail in the answers to that post. We do not believe that this data sufficiently backs up the perceived need to implement such a total prohibition on moderating AI-generated content, nor does it excuse the manner in which Stack Exchange, Inc. went about doing so.

One of the issues that bears specific mention is the company's focus on the accuracy of GPT detectors. This is a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring). Although Philippe continues to characterize this as the basis of the strike to the media, [moderators do not rely blindly on GPT detectors](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389828). As has been noted repeatedly, moderators have long known about and warned flaggers about the inaccuracy of these detectors. We have no objection to ceasing reliance on the detectors, since we already were not relying upon them.

To summarize points raised in just a selection of answers:

- Stack Exchange claims to have a reliable method of detecting GPT posts through draft count. This method has been called into question: it does not appear to consider ways this detection method could fail through trivial action. It also does not match reality as observed by multiple commentators. Many of the remaining conclusions depend on this method being accurate. That is, if the conclusion that GPT posts have fallen based on this detection method is inaccurate, many following conclusions are invalidated. (discussed by [Mithical](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389940), [Gilles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389939), [Kevin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389947), [CodeCaster](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389975), etc.)
- Methodology for handling appeals from suspended users is in question. - Moderators could have been conferred with, for example. ([Ryan M](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389959), [Chris](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389935))
- Multiple answers question or disprove the validity of the data and the claims drawn from it by Staff as a whole. ([starball](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389960), [kaya3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389950), [CodeCaster](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390067))
- Staff appeared to have identified a problem (declining user activity rates), but answers provide alternative explanations for the data displayed that staff appear to have not considered. ([Bryan Krause](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389984), [starball](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389960))

…and this is just a brief overview of some of the first half of the first page of responses.

#### Our conditions for ending the strike

In both the open letter and the Meta post, we have issued several conditions that must be met in order for the strike to end. In light of the developments mentioned above, we wanted to reiterate them here:

- **The prohibition on moderating GPT content must be retracted**.

  This is the immediate, first action that Stack Exchange, Inc. must take in order to begin resolving this issue. This is a non-negotiable, fundamental requirement.
- **The private policy on GPT content that was issued to moderators must be revealed publicly**.

  Stack Exchange, Inc. has put moderators in the untenable position of having a private policy dictating how to handle flags and moderate content that differs from the public version of this policy. The private policy must be retracted and revealed publicly so that the public knows what restrictions moderators were placed under.
- **The data dumps must be re-enabled, and SEDE and API access guaranteed**.

  The data dumps of Stack Exchange content serve to further the goals of free knowledge-sharing. The content posted to the Stack Exchange network was posted to further that goal and with the understanding that it would be freely distributed to anyone seeking knowledge. The data dumps safeguard that collected knowledge and must be continued.

  The Stack Exchange API and Data Explorer both serve as major parts of moderation. Userscripts, queries, bots, and others are used to find, identify, and improve content across the Stack Exchange network. Access to these resources and the data dumps must be allowed to continue unimpeded.
- **Stack Exchange, Inc. must communicate, gather feedback, and act on that feedback before making major policy or software changes to the public platform**.

  Stack Exchange, Inc. has consistently made harmful changes to both policies and the software running the public platform that run counter to the knowledge-sharing goal of the network. Moving forwards, Stack Exchange, Inc. must consult with the community to gather feedback in order to safeguard the goals of the platform.

---

We continue to hope for a speedy resolution to this conflict. We look forward to Stack Exchange, Inc. taking the steps required in order for the network to return to its normal operations, focused on building and maintaining a repository of freely accessible, high-quality information in the form of questions and answers.

Comment: I wonder if the desire to lock down and restrict community content in SO Inc mirrors the tensions that Reddit is currently going through with its own communities. The worry seems to be that "someone might make money from our data", but why is this causing such a backlash with UGC tech companies? This is not a new phenomenon. The data dumps for Stack Overflow from a few months back are still widely available, and could easily be used to train an LLM. I doubt there is anything new in the latest quarterly snapshot that would improve an LLM significantly.

Comment: @halfer My guess is that after the collapse of Silicon Valley Bank, venture capitalists have become far more reticent to continue indefinitely funding massive websites like reddit and SO without seeing a return on investment. They don't seem to understand that when you started off giving their product away, any sort of added cost is an anathema to users. It's going to be very interesting to see what happens when, not if, the VCs blink; or if they're willing to see things go the way of digg.

Comment: @Ian: I don't doubt the VCs would sell their grandmothers if they could be effectively packaged and monetised. But Big Tech's role presumably is to explain to VCs that they're asking for a lot of locks on the UGC stable doors after the data horse has firmly bolted. Plus of course if new data really is desirable, someone will scrape it, either directly or from the search engines. That's my confusion - I can't see why SO isn't siding with the volunteers, because the VC request is essentially unworkable or pointless.

Comment: @halfer As far as the Reddit boycott, I had the same thought as far as training an LLM. The tech is changing all the time though, and if the LLMs aren't trained on examples from the latest tech then people might think of it as less capable. I think it's completely possible that Stack is looking to break into the LLM market, or at least the language data market.

Comment: SE needs to remember that they have exactly the same license, a copyleft one, to our contributions as everyone else does (and that if they build an LLM derived from those contributions, said model is CC BY-SA)

Comment: @halfer I suspect it's a continuation of that thought along the lines "someone might make money from our data *and then we won't be able to do the same* "

Comment: Maybe an unanswerable question @CodyGray but, how unified are the mods in having the restoration of the data dumps as a condition? While I fully respect it, it seems like less of a moderation specific thing and more a general community issue, compared to "our secret mod policy stops you from modding properly".

Comment: I find the "The impact so far" section very thin. How do "ordinary" users of SO notice the impact.

Comment: @SupportUkraine The impact will appear on the site quality, as spam or other content tend to stay longer now. I would think too that support ticket might get longer delay too, as some CM got to visit some site to "help" to handle flags

Comment: @yagmoth555 If you have that experince please post an answer on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425115/what-is-the-impact-of-the-moderation-strike?noredirect=1#comment961315_425115

Comment: @SupportUkraine Too lazy to answer, but I can tell the impact was seen on SF on the other side, like you can see there;  https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/9889/massive-spam-attacks-since-couple-of-days (smokedetector at off and not a lot of user that flag make result like that)

Comment: Congratulations, it appears data dumps are back on, though I'll believe it when it happens.

Comment: Re data dumps being back on by Friday, see [this answer from Philippe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390202/134069).

Comment: @mbrig Virtually all mods who originally supported the strike were *also* in support of adding the condition of getting the data dumps back. Notably, the strike is not meant to be just about moderators' concerns; it is about the broader community, *including but not limited to* moderators, who has invested countless hours into contributing and curating content on these sites, creating the value that they have today, and who maintain a passion for these sites and wish not to see them destroyed. Fortunately, the data dump plank is [now moot](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/390200).

Comment: Awesome. What can an arbitrary user do to support the strike?

Comment: @ThomasWeller generally, just continue to be respectful while cutting back on curation/moderation. (signing on to the letter helps too)

Comment: Very pleased to see that you were selected as a representative. Best of luck. (I also can't help but smile at your new avatar even though I hate though the circumstances that produced it.)

Comment: "Stack Exchange, Inc. **must** communicate," The **"must"** part isn't realistic for a billion dollar company with shareholders, I don't know who had the idea of ending the post on that note but it feels "out of touch".

Comment: @bad_coder-onstrike I get your point, but… look where taking the gentle approach during the Monica incident got us.

Comment: Why do moderators care about CC licenses anyway? The Teacher's Lounge is licensed CC and there is no dump or public access to those "contributions". Moreover, moderators seem to have no objection to content being stripped from the dumps when they delete questions or answers, a power they have to restrict access. They just don't like it when StackExchange restricts access? A bit one-sided if you ask me.

Comment: @CodyGray-onstrike Is there any progress being made, even if you can't say what it is? (Other than data dumps, of course.)

Comment: When there is anything worth reporting, incremental progress is being posted to [the Discord](https://discord.gg/PbEPURd) (in the #rep-announcements channel, which requires agreeing to the conditions in order to get "meta" access). The announcements are generally also cross-posted in one or more chat rooms on SO, including The Ministry of Silly Hats and The Meta Room. [Here is Mithical's latest update](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/56452080#56452080) as of this writing. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: Moderators care about CC licenses of content on the main sites for the same reason that everyone cares about them, @Evan. The Teachers' Lounge contains private, confidential info, so, no, its contents are not dumped publicly. I agree it'd be great if they could be, but, unfortunately, that's just not tenable. Furthermore, the *goal* of the Teachers' Lounge is *not* to build a repository of knowledge. We have no objection to removing content that offers no redeeming value from the data dump. That's the same reason we delete it from the main site.

Comment: It's a condition for us volunteers continuing to devote hundreds of thousands of unpaid (*free*) labor to the billion-dollar company and its shareholders, @bad_coder. I don't think it's unreasonable or unrealistic. Millions of dollars of free labor has *some* cost. Donations often come with conditions or stipulations. These are ours. We would argue that not appreciating the millions of dollars worth of free labor (not to mention *content*, the very content that makes this site worth visiting for anyone) that volunteer moderators and community members provide is the part that is "out of touch".

Comment: I dont get some of these people's attitude. Everything including moderation on this site is voluntary, and they are free to not do it. You knew you weren't going to get anything out of it including any appreciation when you signed up for it. Doing millions of dollars worth of free labour is immaterial. You are always free not to do any of that. I don't understand this sense of entitlement SE or anyone owes them anything. If you feel exploited feel free to not volunteer anymore or even leave the site, why act like you're owed something

Comment: @CodyGray-onstrike I am no more comfortable with you making the determination of what is private and confidential and concluding to withhold all of the teachers lounge's human-generated content, then you are comfortable with having StackExchange making the determination that all answers and questions are regardless of method of origination (human or not) are not private nor confidential and should not otherwise be uniquely withheld.

Comment: @user13267 "why act like you're owed something" I'm not sure whom you mean exactly here (the mods, the company, somebody else) but this strike is not about the moderator work as such. All participants are grown up and know what they are doing. This is simply a power struggle. The company is community driven, i.e. it relies on the community working for them. The community has conditions for that. If the company cannot meet them, this community won't work for them anymore and they should go and try to find another one. That's really all there is to it. Let's see who is more powerful in the end.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution I am not referring to anyone in particular I do not like going after other people in the forum. It's just this general attitude that I have seen from some users who keep mentioning things like "we've provided unpaid work for years" or "SE wouldn't be where it is today if it weren't for us" or "SE should do what we say because we are the community and we built SE". I have also seen this general attitude that some users are, self declared, more "community" than others, because they curated the site more or been here long enough or whatever, when everything here is ...

Comment: ...voluntary anyway and you were always free to not engage with the site. And when you did decide to engage you probably knew you shouldn't have been expecting anything in return, including recognition from SE or other users, or any kind of special treatment in the form of listening to "demands".

Comment: @user13267 I think you're half right, half wrong. Sure, user cannot and should not feel entitled to have a say over the company. Sometimes people mistake a private company with a democracy. And past contributions are fully compensated by past services. No obligations for the future. But - this goes both ways. The company cannot feel entitled to any contribution from the community (or the moderators). The future is fully negotiable (at any time for any reason). And while meta users do not represent the whole community, they represent quite a large bit of it and are quite united here ...

Comment: @user13267 ... so I think the strike is absolutely justified as a means to negotiate the relation between company and community. People here have a right to go on strike. Of course there will be rhetoric (or propaganda) from both sides, but in general the strike is the right thing if you ask me. The company has lost its compass and drifts in AI nonsense instead of doing it (AI and else) the right way.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution I mean, I'm no one to judge if the strike is justified or not. That's not what I was going for in my comment. My comment stands as it is, just an observation of some attitudes I have seen here over the years. Some users want to strike? Go nuts. I have always been of the viewpoint that this is a voluntary site, for people to enjoy in whatever way they personally want. All activities that the striking users want to cease (voting, moderating, flagging, anything) were and have always been voluntary. ...

Comment: ...Do I agree with things the striking users want for ceasing their strike? That's a bit harder to say at this point, because the demands for ending the strike have now morphed into all these idealistic stipulations, like "SE should listen to the community more", "moderators should be allowed to moderate based on the community consensus", etc. Not the exact words but you get the gist. However, there is one point of contention that started this all. You probably know what I am talking about as well. Do I agree with that? Definite no. ...

Comment: ...People should be free to use any tool (AI or not) to generate their posts. As long as someone isn't misusing said tool, it shouldn't be anybody else's business what tool he uses. Sanction users for misuse of tool, instead of having used the tool at all. Using AI/chatgpt as a tool to help in making questions/answers should not be a sanctionable offense.

Comment: @user13267 "People should be free to use any tool (AI or not) to generate their posts." That is surely one of the many opinions. There are arguments for or against it. Currently it seems as if a strong majority of users here disagree and want to keep temporarily banning AI generated content. But one should definitely take into account that not the whole community thinks like this. Some users will be perfectly fine with the current company direction.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution "But one should definitely take into account that not the whole community thinks like this." Exactly what I'm saying. And only those people who think like this does not comprise the entire "community". A question like "what tool someone is allowed to use" this shouldn't even be up for debate as far as I'm concerned. I am happy to keep my mouth shut regarding company direction, just to keep peace and not offend any party, but I can't get behind the idea that some users are allowed to tell other users what tools they can or cannot use

Comment: @user13267 "I can't get behind the idea that some users are allowed to tell other users what tools they can or cannot use" You really don't understand the rationale behind the AI generated content ban? Maybe you are not convinced of it, but one could surely expect that simply copy&pasting some automatic content may not be the same quality on average than human generated content (ok some human generated content is also really bad). The rest is consensus. Communities need (some) rules. If everyone just pleases him/herself we cannot work together.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution I'm not advocating "simply copy&pasting some automatic content". I don't think anyone is saying posting any random AI generated garbage should be allowed. I know what the quality of chatgpt results are for a given category of questions. I have tried generating answers by chatgpt for SE myself, just not posted any because I wasn't satisfied with what I got. Does that mean chatgpt is useless? No. More likely I have no idea how to write a good prompt for it. Then should chaptgpt be completely banned from use here based on answers I saw it generate?...

Comment: ...Absolutely not. Because as a matter of fact, for very specific situations it does give out the exact correct answer, something I have observed as well. Someone who understands chatgpt better can very well make good use out of it to help generate answers here. I would also say that at that point, the onus of making sure the generated answer is correct lies on the poster. The "policy", as it stands right now, bans all such responsible uses of the tool as well, for any user who wants to do so.

Comment: @user13267 "The "policy", as it stands right now, bans all such responsible uses of the tool as well, for any user who wants to do so." If you want to keep copy-pasted content banned but at the same time allow responsible uses, you'll have to come up with a way to differentiate between the two. That is a very interesting question but difficult to answer. I already [asked for it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390324/how-accurately-could-one-differentiate-between-simple-copy-paste-of-ai-generat) and didn't get an answer. Nobody seems to know that.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution "Nobody seems to know that." is exactly why I dont think banning any and all AI is a good idea, especially when it involves one group of users deciding "thats whats its going to be like" for the rest of us. Exactly similar to what you said, there really isnt any way for them to undeniably prove something was generated by chatgpt any way

Comment: @user13267 You also said you want to keep simple copy-pasted AI content banned. So unless you come up with a solution to differentiate that from responsible usage it's either all or nothing. And a strong majority is for banning all content and the community runs on consensus. What more can be said? If you want to change that come up with a way to differentiate AI usages or convince people here of your opinion.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution I never said I want to keep simple copy/pasted AI banned I said I am not encouraging just copy/pasting whatever garbage AI comes up with. They are not the same thing. I may not have a solution right now, heck, I don't even know how an online forum deals with normal spam. But knowing that is not a requirement for using the site and I am pretty a large number of average users don't. I don't think it's just my responsibility to come up with a whole system for a site as complicated as the SE network, just because I disagree with the AI banning policy. ...

Comment: ... And again, I can also ask why it has to be "either all or nothing" when people here themselves acknowledge that there's no way to tell if anything is generated by chatgpt. There are people like those who commented/answered on your linked question who claim they recognise GPT generated content by just looking, but nobody has to take their word for it. If nothing else works, there is always the fallback method of treating every post on it's own merit. If it's correct, upvote it. If not, downvote/delete, instead of worrying about what tool was used to come up with it.

Comment: @user13267 "I never said I want to keep simple copy/pasted AI banned" but you also said "I don't think anyone is saying posting any random AI generated garbage should be allowed." and that sounded to me like you agreed with that part of the ban. Maybe you didn't. In that case the majority still decides. Regarding general spam: moderators simply use their best judgement. That's how they did it in the past and it worked so far. If you want to change the community consensus simply open a question about it and argue for it.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution what you call a "strong majority" I would call a more vocal crowd. At the moment any post that doesn't just say "all ai bad, ban all ai" will get dv/vtc'ed by the vocal mob, so right now there is no possibility of having a logical discussion about it. You say majority decides, I say a topic such as any user's personal freedom to use whatever software tool to generate posts here, should not even be up for debate. I don't want to change any "community"'s consensus or viewpoint or what you want to call it. I am just an average user of the site...

Comment: ... if someone was generating his posts on the site with a software tool, I wouldn't be questioning his methods as long as he was providing content of value to me and the site in general. I just want other users to have the decency to do the same to me if I want to use any tool (chatgpt or whatever) of my choice, instead of trying to gatekeep how the site should be used in the name of "community consensus"

Comment: When you say "that part of the ban" I think you don't understand what the ban is. It's a blanket ban on any part of any post (question/answer) containing any percentage of text/code that was generated by AI. When I say I don't agree with the ban it does not mean "I want any random thing generated by chatgpt allowed to be posted, regardless of whether the thing is right or wrong". Those are different things. If that's how you took it then I'm sorry you didn't understand me correctly.

Comment: FYI for anyone interested, a new update has been posted on the discord channel that Cody Gray [linked above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425100/moderation-strike-update-data-dumps-choosing-representatives-gpt-data-and-wh#comment963134_425100).