# What is the impact of the moderation strike?

Tags: discussion, moderation-strike

There is an ongoing moderation strike.

Both parties have explained their standpoint:

[Moderation Strike update: Data dumps, choosing representatives, GPT data, and where we’re holding](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425100/moderation-strike-update-data-dumps-choosing-representatives-gpt-data-and-wh?cb=1)

[Statement from SO: June 5, 2023 Moderator Action](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389834/statement-from-so-june-5-2023-moderator-action?cb=1)

I wonder how the strike has had an impact on you as a user of SO?

Which kind of strangeness/deteriorations have you noticed?

Comment: The only difference I've noticed so far is that it takes a lot longer to be able to submit an edit to the queue, it says it's full a lot of the time.

Comment: @BrockBrown You also only have 4 flags and 6 edits, so you would have likely seen more consequences if you did more curation. Have you seen any more spam? Depends on how much you use the site, especially if looking at recent questions. No more occurences of NAAs?

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship Right, let me clarify that I submit edits only casually, not rigorously. I do browse pretty frequently though, and answer semi-frequently. It seems like questions still get closed about as often as they usually do, but it takes a little longer for them to get marked as duplicates.

Comment: There's [3300 posts with pending flags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joQ5M.png) (and counting)

Comment: Nothing discernible to the average user.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine Yes, I read that in the linked post. My question is how this impacts the ordinary users. And how does that impact the future of SO.

Comment: I'm an average StackOverflow user - I see some off-topic posts like (fake example) "my cat is meowing, what should I do?" lingering for more than a day instead of being closed.

Comment: A little early to talk about this, IMO. Patience is a virtue. So far I haven't really noticed a difference myself, but I'm not a power user.

Comment: I've seen a lot more trash washing up on MSE (and there are a few questions with comments 'this is blatantly off-topic, but not flagging in support of the strike'

Comment: I do not see any impact, but that is because I have given up on the main site long ago and basically only look at the scifi stack, which somewhat hilariously is moderated and self-policed to a much higher standard than the main site (not blaming mods btw., I just feel that volume over reason is now company policy). I would not trust SO these days to explain to me a "hello world" programm in JS, but if I require high fidelity information on if there is canonical evidence that emperor Palpatine can shoot force lightnings from his toes as well as his fingers, I know where to look.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Don't leave us hanging here. Can he?

Comment: *"I wonder how the strike has had an impact on you as a user of SO"* - For me, not much has changed. I'm still flagging/downvoting/commenting on a lot of very obvious ChatGPT answers, which either results in the User telling me to screw off (and thus me flagging that comment too ), the answer being deleted (either by the User or other community members), or... nothing at all. I've (mostly jokingly) considered recruiting a bunch of 20K+ rep users and collectively nuking these as we find them (via the Downvote > Delete privilege), but that feels wrong. So for now, the crappy content remains 

Comment: in the ancient past we already tried running Q&A site without moderation. In the longer run it ended in tears. ["Sadly, it didn't work out.."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Comment: @code11 [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34342/is-force-lightning-from-the-feet-plausible)

Comment: @TimLewis - How is it wrong to delete garbage contributions? I have no problem downvoting and voting to delete any contributions that (smells, visual identical, and sounds) like garbage generated by OpenAI. I am still not improving contributions. Downvoting and delete votes are essential all I am casting these last couple of days

Comment: @SecurityHound It's not, but it feels wrong to recruit people for the sole purpose of deleting stuff. I'd be reaching out to a few 20k+ rep. members (or whatever the Downvote/Delete threshold is) of my common tags and asking them to keep an eye out for any. We'd then "gang up" and downvote/delete them. I don't _think_ there's any issues with doing that, but it's the "coordinated attack" aspect of it that feels wrong.

Comment: @TimLewis - Isn’t that what Smoke Detector essentially is, as long as you’re not targeting the user, you’re not breaking the spirit of the rules. At the end of the day, if you’re confident this content is generated by an LLM AI, and you find such content unhelpful you should vote accordingly.

Comment: @SecurityHound I'm actually not familiar with what Smoke Detector is (or does), so  yeah, my thought might be the manual equivalent. And you're correct; I am very (99%) confident that these questions are ChatGPT (or other) generated, and are almost always too generic (or straight-up incorrect), and downvote/vote to delete accordingly. My main point is the content remains; if I had 2 other people doing this, i.e. we communicated and coordinated, then we could delete them immediately, as opposed to waiting for a Moderator to do that. But ultimately, it doesn't matter that much 

Comment: @TimLewis - It’s a community ran effort to essentially, flag spam on user’s behalf (have to opt-in), to quickly delete spam. Buts it’s also on strike hence the increase in spam.

Comment: I had someone calling me stupid and making really mean comments about my gender and then later saying that reporting their behavior would do nothing because of the strike. I brought it up in meta and the comments were removed and a community member agreed it was egregious. I think the person may have done this to ensure an impact from the strike. This on top of my fear of posting anything because people can be... idk... mean on the site makes me not want to post here anymore. I always start my questions with, "I'm new at this" so people will be nicer. I have thin skin I guess.

Comment: @MelaniePalen I'm very sad to hear that that happened. Such incidents are uncommon, but I understand how they can put one shy from participating. Whoever gave those ideas was trolling and should not be taken seriously. Although less moderators active means less chances of someone being available to [put a plug on repeated abuse](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396581), suggesting that no moderators will ever do anything because of a strike or a wave or resignations, _while_ also contributing to code of conduct violations, is simply worse than vandalism.

Answer (score 76):

### June 14, 2023

[image: Open flags]

Something of a snapshot of unhandled flags at present. Most of those are comment flags, but there are 600+ mod flags open (mod flags are typically slow to handle). For contrast, we only had around 70 flags in there (and most of those were reminders on large-scale serial plagiarizers).

The real impact is here. This whole list is nothing but SE employees over the last 7 days. Normally these only show up in long-range reports (i.e. yearly) with a handful of flags.

[image: Employee mods]

### June 28, 2023

[image: Open Flags - 7627 on June 28, 2023]

Moderators have handled 676 flags in the previous 7 days. Unfortunately, I can't provide a date range so until we reach the 1 month mark, longer predefined time frames will overlap with a time period before the strike.

Stack Exchange employees have handled 369 flags in the previous 7 days.

The 600+ mod flag number from the previous update is now up to ~1500 (I expect it to reach that at some point today).

### July 6, 2023

[image: 10,180 pending flags]

We've reached (and exceeded) 10k pending flags!

The strike has now gone on for a full month, so full stats can be given for that time period (from June 6, 2023 to July 6, 2023):

- Total flags raised: 33,207
- Average handling time: 5 days, 9 hours, 39 minutes (Note that this stat only includes flags that were actually handled; flags that have never been handled have infinite handling time, and this is not factored into the statistic.)
- Total flags handled by elected moderators who considered themselves "active": 721
- Total flags handled by elected moderators who considered themselves inactive (either due to the strike or other unrelated personal reasons): 1376
- Total flags handled by staff: 1108

### July 25, 2023

[image: 16139 Moderator flags pending]

- Flags raised since June 25, 2023 (one month): 38,549
- Average handling time: 6 days, 15 hours, 8 minutes (Note that this stat only includes flags that were actually handled; flags that have never been handled have infinite handling time, and this is not factored into the statistic.)
- Total flags handled by elected moderators who considered themselves "active": 436
- Total flags handled by elected moderators who considered themselves inactive (either due to the strike or other unrelated personal reasons): 2,282
- Total flags handled by staff: 570

Comment: Dang, they've updated the CSS on that page..

Comment: @BhargavRao Yeah, they condensed a few things and switched to the Stacks way of doing things

Comment: Does it mean that currently no flags are handled by mods on SO? Or are these numbers just on a subset of all possible actions?

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution There are some non-striking mods doing some flag work, but it's not much more than the above numbers

Comment: Is it easily possible to estimate by how much percent flag handling by mods has decreased over the whole network? I guess the ratio is probably much higher than the 22% of mods officially taking part in the strike.

Comment: I don't have anything to compare it to, sadly. I didn't think to look at stats before the strike started

Comment: 33k flags were raised in one month, approx. 3k flags were handled and 10k flags are pending. What happened to the other 20k flags? Did they age away or resolve automatically?

Comment: Yep @Cody, just like #NoData[...], 33,207-(721+1376+1108)=30,002 => 30,002 <<>> 10,180...! => 20K Flags are "missing" in your Post (Update from 2023-07-06, 1 month in the Strike), any explanation...?

Comment: The "total flags raised" number is literally the total number of flags raised. The ~10k number (blue box in screenshot) is the number of posts/comments with at least one active flag. If a post/comment gets multiple flags, the "total flags raised" number will increment, but the number in blue will not.

Comment: Ah OK, got it...! Thanks @Cody... Maybe worth mentioning that in the "Legend" explaining the Numbers... (We were already 2 Users "thinking" that the "Numbers" were not "right"...)

Comment: Well, you're trying to overthink and out-math the statistics. Don't do that. :-)

Comment: Is there a way to know how many posts/comments that are flagged have been handled and how many remain or is it not an interesting metric?

Comment: @Standard_101 The breakdown in the mod console is only for pending flags. Once handled, they all fall into the same bucket of "flags handled". FWIW, staff are handling spam/rude flags and very little else. Even non-striking mods aren't doing much. I don't expect many comment flags have been handled at all.

Comment: Are you planning to give another uodate on this, just to see the trends after the strike? Although a couple of active mods took some time off after the strike, I still am wondering how fast things are going back to "normal". p.s. very late night thoughts, sorry if I am not coherent.

Comment: @M-- There's currently around 6000 flags open, down from the high around 19,000, and the lion's share are moderator flags about ChatGPT. That queue will take a while to get through, especially having to gauge it against the new rules about when we can and can't take action.

Answer (score 71):

Improvement efforts on Stack Overflow slowed way down, leaving junk on the site.  Many Stack Overflow review queue lengths increased.

#### Review Queues and Flags

As I originally wrote this, I didn't have any hard figures about what the queue lengths were before the strike, but I noticed that while some queues have about the same length, some got bigger.

Tracking weekly since Tue. June 13, 2023:

| Date | 1st Q | Close V. | Late Ans. | 1st Ans. | Triage | Sugg. Ed. | Reopen | LQA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| June 13 | 6,274 | 2,716 | 2,017 | 727 | 496 | 495 | 441 | 310 |
| June 20 | 7,044 | 2,745 | 2,319 | 1,296 | 497 | 440 | 364 | 534 |
| June 27 | 6,588 | 2,730 | 2,380 | 1,698 | 496 | 437 | 402 | 782 |
| July 4 | 5,940 | 2,442 | 2,271 | 1,646 | 472 | 496 | 480 | 1,110 |
| July 11 | 6,660 | 2,757 | 2,130 | 2,101 | 500 | 486 | 505 | 1,274 |
| July 18 | 6,168 | 2,755 | 2,252 | 2,451 | 500 | 480 | 499 | 1,365 |
| July 25 | 5,440 | 2,845 | 2,323 | 2,927 | 490 | 489 | 486 | 1,545 |
| Aug. 1 | 5,318 | 2,537 | 2,545 | 2,947 | 499 | 490 | 544 | 1,648 |
| Aug. 8 | 5,084 | 2,734 | 1,971 | 2,510 | 487 | 490 | 459 | 857 |
| Aug. 15 | 4,383 | 2,171 | 2,166 | 1,905 | 491 | 496 | 306 | 321 |
| Aug. 22 | 3,793 | 2,461 | 1,958 | 1,794 | 494 | 494 | 317 | 111 |
| Aug. 29 | 3,736 | 2,371 | 1,552 | 1,661 | 459 | 442 | 215 | 162 |

[image: Review Queue Graph]

Triage and [Suggested Edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345125/suggested-edit-queue-is-full) are capped at 500<sup>a</sup>, so they haven't changed much.

But I noticed reopen votes rising, and one where I had contributed recently, Low Quality Answers, was up a lot.  Low Quality Answers used to hang around 100-150, sometimes dipping into the double digits.  I saw it as low as 17 a couple weeks before the strike.

The obvious implication is that if review time per item is held steady, average time for resolution increased, including flags associated with the review queues.  On Close Votes, votes are more likely to age away, so fewer posts on Stack Overflow that should get closed were getting closed, resulting in more junk visible on the site.

I would imagined that flags piled up, and [Zoe's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425115/what-is-the-impact-of-the-moderation-strike?noredirect=1#comment961320_425115) seems to back up that conjecture.  Problems weren't being remediated.

The site quality went down during the strike.

#### Tag Cleanup

The [connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/connect) tag was in the middle of being [burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418968/the-connect-tag-is-being-burninated).  When I started contributing to that effort a few weeks ago, the tag was still on over 2,200 questions.  A few weeks later, the count got down below 1,100.  But since the strike started and that post was no longer featured, the count has hardly budged.  One June 13, it was on 1,040 questions. There are now 4 questions since July 7 that still have this tag.  Tag cleanups slowed way down.

| Date | Number of Questions with [connect] |
| --- | --- |
| June 13 | 1,040 |
| June 20 | 1,012 |
| June 27 | 1,011 |
| July 4 | 1,002 |
| July 11 | 995 |
| July 18 | 985 |
| July 25 | 969 |
| Aug. 1 | 962 |
| Aug. 8 | 957 |
| Aug. 15 | 935 |
| Aug. 22 | 896 |
| Aug. 29 | 803 |

[image: Connect Tag Graph]

For a Web 2.0 product such as Stack Overflow, if tags are applied incorrectly, and not cleaned up, then the information is not organized as well, making useful answers harder to find.

The site quality went down.

#### Was Stack Overflow Broken?

I don't normally search out spam to flag and destroy it, but one day I saw a few commonly posted spam posts yesterday, about a topic that most certainly does *not* belong here.  I flagged them at the time, and they disappeared soon after, but not as quickly as it usually disappears.

More spam posts lasted longer, more flags piled up, and many review queues piled up as well.  While they got quite large, the flag queues and review queues didn't overflow.  Was Stack Overflow broken<sup>b</sup>?  I don't think it was broken, but it was quite a bit worse than it should have been.

[image: Broken Stack Overflow Mug]

---

<sup>a</sup><sub>I haven't seen Triage go above 500, but I didn't find the reference for when it was increased to 500, just when [it was a long time ago increased to 200](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319131/1-2-3-test-let-s-increase-the-number-of-reviews-close-votes-for-science/320971).</sub>

<sup>b</sup><sub>I had that mug for years, probably ever since I hit 100k on Stack Overflow.  I accidentally knocked it over recently, and this was the unfortunate result.</sub>

Comment: LQA queue was at 54 [about two weeks ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/424895/839601)

Comment: Tag cleanup and tag curation is indeed another rising problem. New tags for off-topic things e.g. [tag:legal] are created but nobody cleans it up, some other new tags might be duplicates for existing ones, but not enough people take care for it. And wrong usage of tags, e.g. [tag:core], doesn't get corrected anymore.

Comment: The close vote queue is almost as before thanks to the auto clean. So it doesn't affect because the queue already had too many item comparing to reviewers

Comment: If you want numbers for the mod-flag queue: Mods had worked hard over the last many months to get the flag queue down. The whole situation started on 2023-05-29, which was when the mod-private, internal policy was posted and a week prior to the strike officially starting. At that time, the SO mod flag queue was in the ballpark of 132 posts with flags (which is a bit different than flags, as a single post may have many flags, particularly if people are flagging a bunch of comments). As of now, the SO moderator flag queue is 5,132 posts with flags, which is the highest I've ever seen it.

Comment: @Makyen  You *might* want to update the flag count there; it's remarkable what just three weeks can do, isn't it?

Comment: @tchrist True. It's currently, 2023-07-12 01:30 UTC,  at [12,100 posts with flags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9VEu.png). [Machavity's answer appears to be kept semi-updated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/425141/3773011), at least more so than I'm doing here in comments.

Comment: "Is Stack Overflow broken?" No, it can run a long time like this. But quality is going down. Fortunately it was quite high. Unfortunately this gets lost every day the strike continues without resolution a bit more. There is so much cleaning up to do and the pile gets larger and larger. I wonder if people actually will come back to this task, or simply leave or remain where they are.

Comment: So, the LQA queue keeps growing, and I'm not even flagging anymore. Yep, low quality keeps piling up. A good indicator of why moderation is necessary. I wonder when SE Inc. will arrive at that conclusion as well, and stop stifling moderators' ability to, y'know, moderate.

Comment: rgettman, do you wanna add a plot showing the trends? https://i.stack.imgur.com/cR5uN.png I can update the plot every week (not that it is anything special), but it will make it easier to see that the numbers are on the rise.

Comment: It seems a bit complicated to draw real conclusions from queue sizes for queues that require an act of moderation to put something in the queue, a corresponding moderation act to clear something from the queue, and that have flags that age away if no-one handles them.

Comment: @M-- I added graphs with this week's stats.

Comment: Thank you. Gosh, I wish we had stats for a couple of weeks before the strike.

Comment: I think an interesting table for the review queues would have been how many reviews were _completed_ in each queue. The CV Queue, for example, refreshes its content automatically as close votes age away.

Comment: @TylerH Here's my first crack at a SEDE query for completed reviews per queue per week (data is updated on Sundays): https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1774232/review-tasks-per-day-around-the-strike

Comment: see also this message by Zoe in Burnination HQ saying she'll let the room freeze and explaining why: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/56521618#56521618

Answer (score 57):

Surprisingly I didn't see as much spam as I would have expected as Smokey (Smoke Detector, a bot which detects spam and other garbage) is on strike too, but the spam I saw stayed a lot longer (sometimes even > 2 hours) instead of something between a few seconds to a few minutes like before.

But with most of the experienced curators and mods on strike, I see a lot more wrong handling of spam and troll posts, esp. 1 or 2 close votes after the spam/troll post was already visible for more than an hour and often double digit numbers of views. If every viewer, or at least half of the viewers would correctly flag the post as spam (or rude/abusive in case of trolling), the post would never get so many views. One of these [support number spams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YEC1.jpg) was closed as "not about programming" by 3 users who are on SO for 3 to 13.5 years. Today [a troll post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNBbO.jpg) was closed as "needs more focus".... That's so wrong. It was closed after 2 minutes but it took more than 24 hours until it was deleted as R/A.

Probably Smokey and the curators did such a good job before, that the average user hardly ever saw any spam and thus never had to figure out how to handle it.

Aside from that, I see a lot of posts still open with 0 to 2 close votes after days that usually would have been closed at least on the day of posting, and a lot of posts in dire need of a good edit.

Today and in the last few days I saw several cases of non-English questions that got answered before they got closed, (or even not yet closed after several hours, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76601525/authentication-api-failed-to-recognize-jwt-token)). The answers are in some cases in English, but in one case it was in the same language as the question. All this might have happened before but in most cases, non-English questions have been closed in minutes without getting answers.

Comment: I understand that the site has reduced the necessary threshold for automatic spam deletion from six flags to four. This probably explains a lot of what you're seeing.

Comment: The longer spam posts uptime you mention is probably the reason why I had seen more of it recently.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel ok, that would explain why I see less spam. But where did you get this from? Was it announced somewhere?

Comment: @jps [Message in CHQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11540?m=63742488#63742488)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: This suggests an obvious way to make mayhem. Not that I'd do it.

Comment: I've seen spam that's lasted about 4 days. But not *really* obvious spam

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390642/stack-exchange-needs-its-own-spam-system has some zesty spam from today in a screen shot.

Comment: @tripleee Oh, yum. That’s a lot of delicious food right there.

Comment: [This spam has been up nearly a month](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76504219/471272). Check the final paragraph.

Comment: Number of spam posts that lasted for [10](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1768124/number-of-spam-posts-that-lasted-at-least-ten-minutes-per-week?min=10#graph),
[30](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1768124/number-of-spam-posts-that-lasted-at-least-ten-minutes-per-week?min=30#graph), [60](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1768124/number-of-spam-posts-that-lasted-at-least-ten-minutes-per-week?min=60#graph)
minutes (per week).

Comment: The same number counted per month: [10](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1768123/number-of-spam-posts-that-lasted-at-least-ten-minutes-per-month?min=10#graph), 
[30](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1768123/number-of-spam-posts-that-lasted-at-least-ten-minutes-per-month?min=30#graph), 
[60](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1768123/number-of-spam-posts-that-lasted-at-least-ten-minutes-per-month?min=60#graph).

Answer (score 42):

I wasn't aware of the strike until today, and the last days I had started to wonder about the increased amount of obvious spam posts I was flagging (per time).

Comment: You’re more than welcome to join in. SE has banned us from featuring posts related to the strike. If you wish, you can sign [the letter](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/), and read more details in the [MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an).

Comment: "SE has banned us from..." - I've been wondering: what exactly are they supposed to be able to do about that?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel See the various initial posts about the strike across the meta sites. SE staff engaged in rollback wars with the community, repeatedly removing the tag.

Comment: They were very clear that they would not allow posts promoting the strike to be tagged [featured], and they would be removing the [featured] tag if it were added by a moderator, whether out of protest or ignorance. They've been consistent about doing so. I have to praise Philippe for, in a rare show of integrity, doing this himself, rather than sending a minion to do so and thus absorb the flak. Also, to their credit, they've allowed Meta posts *about the policy* to be [featured], and done nothing to prevent Meta posts about the strike from becoming and remaining Hot Meta Posts. (cc @Karl)

Comment: @CodyGray-onstrike "I have to praise Philippe for, in a rare show of integrity, doing this himself, rather than sending a minion to do so" Yeah? What about Prashanth Chandrasekar?

Comment: What about him, @Lundin? This was Philippe's decision, so he implemented it.

Comment: @CodyGray-onstrike Regarding sending someone else when making announcements, policy changes, changes to the core products of the company and so on.

Answer (score 40):

> Which kind of strangeness/deteriorations have you noticed?

1. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76449451/7353417) has been online for 5 days now, without any action from us.
2. These answers look like ChatGPT answers, all by the same author (some have been online for more than a week):
   [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76470542/7353417)
   [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76425141/7353417)
   [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76426160/7353417)
   [4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76425635/7353417)
   One is accepted, with a downvote.

I fall into the category of programming enthusiasts; I can help others only for easy, basic problems, and of course doing my review queues. But **I didn't raise any flag**, trying to give my little help to the ongoing strike. I'm now in "read-only" mode. I know that my decision will have a very little impact on SO, but I'm firmly convinced that mods did the right thing. I really love SO, and I think that mixing AI with human content is a kind of quick self-destruction.

**EDIT**
Another deterioration:
As soon as I posted this answer, all my links were upvoted. It seems that someone does not understand the difference between using an AI and a high quality site, with verified content. That's very sad.

Comment: Even if every single person only has a small impact (and most of us only have small impacts) then together it can still add up to something big and relevant. I can only agree with this answer.

Comment: @prusswan *what's the harm...* -- If Stack Overflow deteriorates into a relay station for AI traffic we have a serious problem. IMO, Stack Overflow should be a site of humans talking to humans, otherwise contributing will become incredibly tiring and active expert users like me will quit.

Comment: @prusswan "what's the harm with answering chatgpt questions with chatgpt answers?" - _none_, if you never try to search for answers before posting a question of your own. For diligent people who search before asking the harm is evident.

Comment: Boah...!, your "online question for 5 days" is not soooooo bad, what about [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76418464/3799241), ah-ah...!? => Online for 10 days already, I tried to flag it 9 days ago as "Blatantly Off-topic" (= "Not suited for this site"), my Flag is still 'Pending', I'm nearly surprised it's not in 'Aged away' Status yet... With some random Tags selected, and '-1' Score (my Downvote), only 21 more days to wait until it will finally get roomba'd, ah-ah...! // Oh...!?, 'Roomba' is not on strike, "I hope"...!?

Answer (score 39):

Today was literally the first time in ~4 years that I have seen an actual spam post.

I must say, while I fully support the strike, it will take a very long time until the quality of SE sinks below the alternatives. I'm still way way better served here than with a plain Google search.

One point I don't get is why the SE management even tries to go against the mods with their decision regarding the AI. I can imagine why one would disable data dumps (e.g. there's a prospective buyer for such data, and greed outweighs other reasons). But when experts across the network tell that AI-generated answers are killing the quality of the site, and mods are willingly doing their best to keep it up despite the flood, why would one actively get in their way?

Comment: Regarding your last sentence, it only makes sense if you assume that the company actually really believes that the mods are doing more harm than good. For the company it reads like: When experts across the network hallucinate AI-generated answers and suspend users they are killing the quantity of the sites, mods willingly are doing their worst and the company needs to actively stop them in order to preserve harm from innocent users answering questions. There are two very opposite stories going around here.

Comment: I think it has been clear for a long time that Corporate's goals for the site and the metrics it pays the most attention to have diverged significantly from those of most of the mods, major curators, and active answerers.  With respect to AI-generated content in particular, I think Corporate genuinely cares more about even a small number of false positives than it does about the large number of true positives.

Comment: Quality is not easy to put into a [KPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performance_indicator) (thus was never a serious concern (for the company)). It is about quantity. The logic was that the reduction in number of people answering questions was due to heavy-handed handling of ChatGPT plagiarisers. Whereas using [Occam's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam's_razor), it is [more likely due to answerers getting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/425098) [FGITWed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19533) by ChatGPT plagiarisers (or just the perception or the expectation of such FGITWing).

Comment: I have seen such a case of FGITWing yesterday by chance (more or less). The ChatGPT plagiariser was the first to post.

Comment: They're legitimately [pushing a tool](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425162/5079428) that *integrates* ChatGPT-like content into the site. Can't push a tool if your mods are going to ban its output, I suppose.

Comment: @Chris-RegenerateResponse that opens up a whole set of new opportunities for everyone, welcome to the brand new field of ChatGPT consultancy

Comment: @Chris-RegenerateResponse I see no reason to allow AI-based answers just because users can use AI to format their questions. There's no incentive for the poster to leave AI hallucinations in their question, is there?

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution What I see is that ChatGPT abusers are statistically low-rep users posting well-written answers with proper formatting, and after seeing a bunch of such answer I grew very cautious towards new low-rep contributors. I'm sure this creates just the kind of friendly and welcoming atmosphere SE was striving to achieve with all the recent CoC changes. /s

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev The company would say that low-rep users posting well-written answers with proper formatting is probably an expression of professionalization of new users and such answers should be welcomed with open arms. Without them, nobody will post answer anymore soon.

Comment: Maybe because the actual users, not the moderators, are on the side of SE management on this: most software developers now use ChatGPT4, so it's a trend one cannot stop. It's either that, or questions on SE never getting answered & traffic to SE dropping further...

Comment: ^ Well that's a load of BS.

Comment: @TomWenseleers: What Cerbrus said.

Comment: @TomWenseleers Indeed "getting more traffic" and "getting quality answers" are two different goals, perhaps even contradicting ones. I for one would not want ChatGPT answers on my questions, I can get these myself.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Of course - don't mean users should just start copying & pasting plain ChatGPT responses (that should be banned)-what I mean is that VERIFIED ChatGPT answers, with extra effort put in (adding authoritative sources, benchmarks, correct output, etc), should be allowed. Stuff along the lines of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48119360/performant-2d-sdl-or-opengl-graphics-in-r-for-fast-display-of-raster-image-using, which now gets deleted if it mentions that part of the code came out of ChatGPT4. Unless policy is that ChatGPT4 can be used as inspiration but can't be mentioned.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev This was my long rant about it. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387575/examples-of-chatgpt-being-right-and-wrong-on-stack-exchange/390348#390348 But no, I don't expect that any of you would agree or would upvote an answer like that...

Comment: I am starting to see a significant impact on quality. Users are abusing the situation and submitting dozens of answers that are obviously generated by OpenAI or similar LLM. Furthermore they are allowed to use these LLM to literally argue with users in chat. These same users abuse the voting system and serial downvote your own contributions. Let’s not even get into spam, the low quality trash answers, stuff that would typically last a day at most last several days or even weeks. If this is a glimpse into the future of the quality control I will find a better community.

Comment: I haven't seen any spam posts here, but I certainly have seen it over on SU since the strike began!

Comment: @TomWenseleers I was going to answer you in a comment, but ended up writing this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392737/294404

Answer (score 32):

### Less editing means more dirty posts

Some of the striking curators would often handle general clean-up of posts to remove greetings, rants, and other kinds of fluff as they arrived.
It's been 23 days since the strike, so we can probably grasp some changes in the amount of fluff in recent posts by now.
For this quick experiment, we'll consider search pages of size 50 and time ranges with 23 days:

- after the strike: 2023-06-05 to 2023-06-28,
- before the strike: 2023-05-13 to 2023-06-04

##### "Thanks in advance"

As of 2023-06-28 around 12:00 UTC, searching for the *Newest* posts with the query `Thanks in advance` resulted in 63 full pages. Page 64 would feature posts from both Jun 5 and Jun 4, so it was discarded in these calculations.

Going further down the search pages for posts between 2023-05-13 and 2023-06-04, page 112 featured posts from both May 13 and May 12. So we have around 112 - 64 = 46 full pages.

This represents an increased rate of unedited posts by 37% relative to the time just before the strike.

##### "Hope this helps"

Doing the same experiment with the query `hope this helps`, we get 43 full pages (almost 44) of posts since the beginning of the strike.

In the interval of same length between 2023-05-13 and 2023-06-04: 79 - 44 = 35 full pages.

This represents roughly an increased rate of unedited posts by 23%.

### Rude comments stay for longer

Remember one of the things that [make Stack Overflow feel unwelcoming](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366733)? These forms of code of conduct violations
(and many others) may stay visible on the site for longer. Persistent troublemakers may also have more time to cause harm before they are suspended.

A few samples of comments **still visible** at the time of writing:

> F*ck to all down voters. At least provide the reason for down vote.
> [posted 2023-06-23 08:09:41](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/134949538)

> someone is so ignorant and thinks of himself as he knows everything and considers this question stupid, thus down voted my question and its answers.
> [posted 2023-06-21 10:46:16](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/134922719)

> SO sucks, this question is great and it got downvoted. What a toxic toxic community..
> [posted 2023-06-14 14:13:56](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/134842598)

> What insecure and salty person down-voted this? Seems we have rampant hateful down-voting on SO these days.
> [posted 2023-06-14 22:11:35](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/134848128)

> This answer is tested. Don't know which idiot downvoted it.
> [posted 2023-06-09 16:32:17](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/134788674)

Naturally, any example that I place here may end up being deleted quickly now, due to the Meta effect.

There will also be more meta-commentary in general, making questions harder to navigate through and leaving more room for heated quarrels and rude comments. These may well be some of the worst times to interact with someone on Stack Overflow, as stories such as [these](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396581) may well repeat themselves more easily.

### Non answers staying visible

Other posts in this Meta question have brought up the problem that so many low quality questions are being upvoted and answered, further diluting and making this repository less useful bit by bit. But sometimes it's even worse than that: answers which do not answer the question at all, such as a rant from the OP, are not deleted in a timely fashion, and are sometimes even marked as accepted. Here is an [example from Jun 13 at 13:46](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76465612), still visible at the time of writing.
This means that any visitor who has the same problem and finds this question (which claims to hold an accepted answer) will be met with betrayal. Some people are petty indeed, and these levels of pettiness make things worse for everyone, but at least we can clean up after the fact, for as long as moderation continues.

### Each number tells its story

It might also help shed some light to show an example of a curator's flagging patterns.
In the same time interval from above, from before the strike, I cast more than 480 helpful comment flags. At least 50 of them are still in review. Experience tells me that the number of flags I would have raised would not have gone far from this. Multiply the difference by all the other users who would have flagged comments regularly and you get a hefty amount of flags that would have [piled up on the already large numbers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/425141) hinted by moderators.

### Most of the effects are long term anyway

In any case, the lack of proper moderation creates a lingering effect that is hard to measure with small pieces of evidence. By the time it had its effect, we'll probably have much less interest in the site in general.

Comment: 4 hours later and the comments are still up! 

Comment: Comments now flagged and deleted.

Answer (score 21):

*Regular* spam questions on SE Meta:

> [image]
> <sub>(1st and 3rd in that screenshot, obviously)</sub>

These questions now tend to survive for 5-15 minutes, depending on time of day. Normally, these questions would barely even pop up on the frontpage, due to Charcoal catching them quickly.

The contents are also ironic: A paragraph or 2 of AI-generated text followed by a link.

Comment: Meta SE still has an active moderator, and (believe it or not), that isn't a lot of spam. Academia SE (with all its mods on strike) had a spam wave the other day. They posted until every question on the home page was spam and then started answering some. Multiple spammers had [10–15 posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391050/323179) and some were over an hour old, to the point where there were several users who were flagging who ran out of flags.

Comment: @Laurel and I'd assume there's also users still manually flagging spam. That example on Academia is, frankly, impressive xD

Answer (score 8):

I just saw this post, and thought I might add to it.

As a regular user with not much rep, I'm not able to contribute to the review queues, so I'm not aware of changes in those stats.

However, I was a decent flagger before the strike. Of the flags I raised before the strike, I have seen a drastic decrease in the flag-handling - before the strike, any flags I raised would be handled within 24 hours (most even within a few hours). As of now, the flags I have raised are gradually aging away.

Even though the posts those flags were raised on are low-quality, they are remaining open and visible, in contrast to pre-strike when such content would be gone within a day.

Voting has also drastically decreased (which could also be because of the new voting button design):

[image]

Comment: While voting may have gone down with the strike, I'm not sure that your screenshot is really enough to back up this claim, since none of these questions have more than a handful of views.

Comment: It's unsurprising that flags are starting to age away. Within a few hours there will be 10,000 pending flags (up from 78 in mid-May).

Comment: Not very clear what your Screenshot is about, with all Qt's with [2-4] Views, and "how" you flagged them... // Absolutely all Qt's I ever flagged before the Strike (as anything (Duplicate/Blatant Off-Topic/Low Qlt/whatever)) have always aged away, I don't see much change with the Strike... (But I just monitor a "small" Tag..., for which 'Roomba' is much more efficient than flagging...)

Answer (score 4):

It's an indirect effect, since moderation on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com) is done entirely by SE, but I've noticed that rules-violating proposals are sticking around much longer.  Instead of being closed within a day for "lack of community" or "being about web3", these proposals are lasting long enough to run into one of the automatic deadlines.

Comment: Well, that is unfortunate (but thanks for sharing anyway). I doubt this is related to the strike, though. My guess would be more that this is because [staff is no longer interested in Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390463) and thus no longer paying much attention.

Comment: @CodyGray-onstrike, right up until the strike started, things like the "Move" proposal were being closed almost immediately, with an appropriate message.  I'm guessing that whoever was keeping an eye on things got re-tasked to try to keep StackOverflow from going too far out of control.

Answer (score -42):

There is so much content/depth on SO, that even if it goes into read-only indefinitely, it can still be useful for years to come. Can't say the same for other SEs

I mainly come in from search engine results, if Google does not take it upon itself to moderate the interwebz, I don't see why SE volunteers need to be so hard on themselves. The queues and flags never bothered me, so I expect the same for everyone else.

Not that I stand for or against the strike, but I noted my usage patterns already fulfill 4 out of 5 strike criteria for normal users, as I very rarely interfere with the content (unless it is so bad that I felt the need to participate):

> Even if you are not a moderator you can participate in the strike by:
>
> ```
> Not voting on posts
> Not submitting edits
> Not reviewing in the review queues
> Not commenting
> Not flagging posts
> ```

Comment: Perhaps you don't realize that finding mostly relevant content on SO (with Google or otherwise) is possible exactly because SE volunteers have been "hard on themselves", spending their time on removing noise and banning users who only post noise.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev the search engine also needs to be able to rank content ahead of junk, if SO quality drop enough it will simply be replaced by better content. I don't particular rely on any single site for knowledge

Comment: Perhaps [2022: a year in moderation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422885/2821954) might help to give a big picture of community moderation...

Comment: @prusswan That is true, however, search engine ranking is only useful if you search for something popular, like "string length in python". If you search for an arcane linker error message from a seldom-used library, then "relevant" becomes very different from "popular". Google will feed you with pages and pages of common linker errors before you see anything remotely useful.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev but SO is also best for popular stuff only, as my attention shifted to more unusual/rare topics over time there is no guarantee I can find what I need on SO, sometimes just with a very low vote which is hardly an actual reflection of usefulness. For linker errors, maybe back to the MSDN forums, Github issues (if library/repo related) or any other credible C++/C# forums. Or even a site dedicated to linker errors

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev rather than relying on SO, I put my faith in people behind the content

Comment: I ask some people about this recently. See https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/92764?m=56410885#56410885 .

Comment: @prusswan Yeah, and why do you think you can’t find useful stuff on SO? Because we’re being overrun with trash.

Comment: @prusswan The curators I know of would rather vote to delete your question, if it’s pointlessly bad, and serves no purpose on SO. I’m happy they discovered some garbage of mine that the site didn’t let me delete, because people had posted answers.

Answer (score -78):

I haven't noticed any increase in spam. What I *am* seeing is questions that need improvement remaining open long enough to be clarified and answered. The site is actually welcoming to new users for the first time in years. I'd prefer it if the moderators remained on strike forever.

Comment: Downvotes on meta are a badge of honor.

Comment: Closed questions can also be clarified and edited which will bring them to the Reopen Queue. If they are properly improved they will be reopened and can be answered. The only consequence of strike will be more garbage and useless posts that will make this place less useful for anyone looking for solutions. You cannot easily find diamonds in a swamp.

Comment: Be careful what you wish for, as it might just come true... looking at my own reps history, it's the "new users", not mods, who should be kept in read-only mode for the first year or two

Comment: Care to share examples of questions that "stayed open long enough to be clarified and answered"? Then I will show you example of reopened questions... it's easy to point fingers, make baseless claims, and undermine the great job that curators (moderator or not) have done to give you the site that you are now enjoying. But data will debunk those claims.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Closed questions aren't reopened often enough. Closing them intimidates new users into not improving them. I maintain, as I have for years, that nothing should ever be closed or removed. Moderation is superfluous; search engines do a great job of finding diamonds in a swamp.

Comment: @M--ßţřịƙïñĝ The curation of this site is terrible by design. The vast majority of developers consider it a joke.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Not sure if I've seen you in chat, but you could've posted reopen-pls requests for the questions which you are confident should be reopened, in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers).

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede That's one of the reasons [we're striking](https://openletter.mousetail.nl). We've been asking for better curation tools for a long time, but we're constantly neglected.

Comment: @AndreasdetestsAIhype More effective tools for negative curation would not be better.

Comment: Then what is positive curation? (Please be realistic)

Comment: @AndreasdetestsAIhype Instead of removing "bad" content, tag "good" content. The idea that you can build a collection of knowledge the way this site currently operates is, quite frankly, totally insane.

Comment: So you're asking us to waste a ton of valuable curation time by simply ignoring bad content when we see it? What a totally, insanely ineffective way to curate a knowledge base. ;)

Comment: @AndreasdetestsAIhype Bad content doesn't affect anything. Let people browse all content or only positively curated content as they see fit.

Comment: Again, would you provide evidence for your claims? I am striking so I am not happy with the state of things, but considering SO a joke?!! I don't know of a serious developer who has not used SO at some point in their career. I am still waiting for the examples btw. And your suggestion for leaving bad content up is what we see with many other "forums" which are cluttered with garbage and are no use (yet I don't think of those as a joke neither).

Comment: p.s. Downvotes are not a badge of honor, but an indication that your idea is not very popular. Let's be realistic and make claims and suggestions that can be backed up by logic and/or data.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede What you're asking for, is a site with no limits. Is SO really what you're seeking? Why aren't you on any other site with none of the limits of SO? Why do you choose to be on SO? Could it be because the limits and curation here are valuable, and give you a reason to stay here?

Comment: And even if the limits of SO aren't why you're here, they're a reason why many others are here, including those that answer a lot of questions, and help developers directly like that. So if you're here because others are here, because there's a community here, and because answers can be found here, keep in mind that all this is here because of the limits, the scope, and the curation.

Comment: is this the type of website that you are looking for: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37009529#comment8? No curation whatsoever.

Comment: @AndreasdetestsAIhype The value here comes from SO being the "default" site to share this kind of information. Curation detracts from that value, and always has. The vast majority of developers - I'd say 95% - are driven away by negative curation. (Source: polling my co-workers for about as long as this site has existed.)

Comment: But why do you think SO is the default site, and why do you think history had it that way? (Sidenote: your source is very bad; it's not representative)

Comment: @AndreasdetestsAIhype already informed you about shortcomings of your source, but to give you an equivalent example... Yankees sucks, Sox rules (source: I have been polling my college friends for 10 years).

Comment: @M--ßţřịƙïñĝ Invalid analogy. Correct analogy: Yankees sux, *therefore I do not go to Yankees games.* This makes it a fact, not an opinion.

Comment: @AndreasdetestsAIhype SO was originally friendlier before a "community" of bullies established the moderation policy. It remained the default because of barriers to entry and limited marginal utility in an alternative. Thanks to the actions of both moderators and management, marginal utility has now vastly increased. It's just a matter of time before someone overcomes the barriers to entry and this site becomes irrelevant.

Comment: @M--ßţřịƙïñĝ The noise in the AOSP issue tracker is because of Google's monumentally incompetent mishandling of bug reports, not a lack of curation. The outpouring of rage on improperly closed issues represents more of "community" than this site currently has.

Comment: Honestly, I am done asking for facts, as it seems best I'd get is some poll you claim you held amongst your colleagues. My attempt at providing a baseball example was to show you that referring to a random "poll of opinions" among your peers is a ridiculous basis to form any opinion, let alone to be used as "facts and figures" for convincing others. Yet it seemed you are focused on the argument and results that I've drawn based on that "joke". So, sadly it seems that I failed to convey my message.

Comment: @M--ßţřịƙïñĝ This isn't debate club. In real life, we use heuristics. That's also not the only heuristic that points to me being correct. Go over to /g/ and ask what people think of this site.

Comment: "Bad content doesn't affect anything" Sure, until you search for a problem you're having and find a bunch of people who mostly had some unrelated problem but described it badly, or a bunch of unanswered duplicate copies of the question with no links to the actual answer.  Do you know why that mostly *doesn't* happen?  (hint: it's because of curation)

Comment: I recently went through dozens of questions about a particular error message and removed unhelpful ones, marked duplicates as duplicates, etc.  You can now *actually* find the answer without trawling through ten pages of search results.

Comment: @RyanM-Regenerateresponse What *usually* happens is I search on Google, and Google takes me to a helpful Q&A that was closed for some stupid reason.

Comment: Again, please provide evidence for these claims. If you believe specific questions are incorrectly closed, you could bring them up for discussion on meta.

Comment: It seems like you just wish for this platform to be something different than what it was intended for. I'm sure there's lots of other sites that can fulfill that exact purpose. There's no need for SO to also do so.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede You claim that SO used to have another goal in the past, and that nothing should be removed from the site, and that things changed only later, when "bullies" took over. This is not true. Listen to this [speech from the founder of SO, Joel Spolsky](https://youtu.be/1jeCt_WTFhE?t=1747). Timestamped at 29:07.

Comment: "I haven't noticed any increase in spam." - [You are not paying attention.](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/9889/massive-spam-attacks-since-couple-of-days).  I am seeing multiple spam posts from the same user, submitting half a dozen answers to those questions, and they are not being deleted for hours sometimes.  " I maintain, as I have for years, that nothing should ever be closed or removed." - This is short sighted, if nothing is closed or removed, that would include spam and we would be worse the Quroa or Yahoo Answers.

Comment: @SecurityHound Not nearly as short-sighted as chasing off 95% of your potential user base.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede - Allowing garbage AI generated content will drive off actual users with real knowledge. I will leave, delete my thousands of answers, and never look back if AI generated content is allowed. I will continue to downvote, low quality garbage AI generated content, regardless if it’s allowed or disallowed. Moderation is required for any user generated community like Stack Exchange. Low quality contributions have no place, if low quality contributions are allowed, then I have no reason to provide my high quality contributions

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede - 100% of the AI generated content I have seen has been complete garbage. I am not going anywhere, my downvotes on legitimate garbage content, will continue