# Should we create a new tag for a NuGet package which is a port of another package from .NET Framework 4 to .NET Core?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently [posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76517799/3092298), and created the [elmahcore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elmahcore) tag. Elmah is a popular logging utility for .NET Framework 4 web applications. It appears to only work with the older version of the framework. I have a .NET 7 web application, and decided to use [ElmahCore](https://github.com/ElmahCore/ElmahCore), which is a port of Elmah to .NET Core/7+. Upon asking the question, I created the "elmacore" tag, and gave it some usage guidance (which is currently under review):

> ElmahCore is a port of [elmah](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elmah) from .NET Framework 4 to .NET Core, which provides an application-wide error logging facility for ASP.NET Core web applications.

While cruising the [elmah tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elmah), I am seeing a mix of .NET 4 and .NET Core questions. There are API differences between Elmah and ElmahCore, but also some overlap. It's not quite a port from one platform to another in the same way that NHibernate for .NET is a port of Hibernate from Java. It was causing some confusion for me, not just in choosing the NuGet package to begin with, but also for searching questions on StackOverflow.

Now I am second-guessing my choice to create a new tag. Was this a proper use case for adding a new tag, or should we rely on questions being tagged [elmah](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elmah) and [asp.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core) to know the question pertains to the ElmahCore NuGet package rather than the Elmah NuGet package?

---

I did tag a few questions with [elmahcore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elmahcore), but stopped to ask this question, hoping if I goofed up I wouldn't create so much work for the mods.

Comment: If the API is not quite the same, and if version numbers can overlap, then I'd say it it correct to have a specific tag, but I have no implications in any .NET tags, so take my advice with a grain of doubt, until someone more well-versed into .NET tags confirms (or rejects) my claim.

Comment: I voted to close because I did not read the question title clearly. Sorry about that.

Comment: @George that's an interesting custom close vote reason.

Comment: "*... hoping if I goofed up I wouldn't create so much work for the mods.*", but the Mods are [on Strike](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425115/3799241), so use your "best Judgement" especially if you are a bit "knowledgeable" in the Tag(s), to leave as little "mess" as possible to (need to) clean up after the Strike... :idea:

Comment: You've gone [full penguin mode](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/katy-t3h-pengu1n-of-d00m) again, haven't you @chivracq?

Comment: Hum..., @CodeCaster, what's "wrong" with my previous Comment...? What I meant is that because of the current Strike, it's "maybe" not the best time/timing for some Tag "Management", and/or that OP probably won't get an Answer until after the Strike... (That's all, nothing related to some "Linux Mode" or whatever you may refer to...)

Comment: @chivracq you know quite well how your writing style makes your comments practically unreadable. And if not, you do now.

Comment: IMO, `elmah-core` would be a better tag, but it can be added as a synonym.

Comment: @IanKemp: I considered that, but the NuGet package is literally named "ElmahCore" rather than "Elmah for .NET Core".