# What to do if a user initiates a downvote war because I've been pointing out that their answer posts look like ChatGPT?

Tags: discussion

Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2K3s.png) of my comments history. Here's some example links:

[How to build multi module jib image with nested modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76675906/how-to-build-multi-module-jib-image-with-nested-modules/76675920#comment135183586_76675920)

[What is torch.nn.Module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76675900/what-is-torch-nn-module/76675927#comment135183581_76675927)

[How to include parameter and event in a function in sveltekit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76675996/how-to-include-parameter-and-event-in-a-function-in-sveltekit/76676005#comment135183571_76676005)

And here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcqDP.png) of my reputation tab.

I think it's pretty clear that they're spamming ChatGPT generated answers because;

- All answers are written 1 minute apart.
- All answers are written within 2 minutes after the question was asked.
- The overall *style* of the answers.

I can say with almost certainty that they downvoted my posts because their reputation (excluding the rep from an accepted answer and downvotes) is down since I commented on their posts. I also didn't downvote their posts because it might help OP but users should be aware of the fact that the answers were generated by a LLM so I just commented.

So here's the main question: What can be done about this? Shouldn't there be a report option for users' whole profiles, or is it always on a case-by-case basis?

Comment: If someone has serially downvoted, those votes will be reversed automatically as there is a script that runs once a day (I think) which picks up such voting patterns and removes such votes. However, it may not pick up all of them. also users can downvote in less obvious manner, and such votes are not reversed. When you start moderating content you should be prepared to that. You can also flag your post for moderator attention, but this is not worthwhile for few votes.

Comment: As far as ChatGPT posts are concerned, if you want to avoid negative reaction, don't comment and flag with custom mod flag explaining that you suspect it is AI generated. Because of the strike such flags will not be immediately handled, but that is fine as those flags don't age.

Comment: You only need to flag one of that user's posts not all of them, and you can link to many posts in that flag if there are problems with many posts; there's no need for a flag user feayas it already exists in the flagging system.

Comment: related on MSE: [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/997587)

Comment: @ThomA, should I flag them under the "In need of moderator intervention" or "Plagiarized content"?

Comment: Here on MSO: [What should I do if I suspect that a question or answer is written by ChatGPT?](/q/421988/11107541). See also the slightly related (on the topic of downvotes (and because you said "war")): [Should I serial downvote ChatGPT answers?](/q/425463/11107541), which I have written an answer of my own stance on.

Comment: For CrapGPT content you want "in need of moderator intervention".

Comment: @CodyGray-onstrike Sorry, you are right. Deleted. I'm not saying they are serial downvoting though; it's just in case someone wants to check out their recent contributions.

Comment: Thanks, @InSync. I knew you weren't meaning to make accusations, but we all have to be careful on Meta in how we present things. If someone really wants to go find the user, there's enough information in this question to do it. It doesn't need to be made any easier by linking their profile directly. (Naturally, I hope that anyone who goes and seeks out a user's content would *only* be doing it with the aim of bringing stuff to moderators' attention via flags, not taking matters into their own hands with vigilante harassment. But, unfortunately, I've seen bad things happen on Meta before.)

Comment: Just repeating Dalija a bit: if you suspect someone is abusing the site (e.g. ChatGPT, spamming, trolling, being abusive, voting fraudulently, etc.) best not confront them and just leave it to the mods. Putting yourself on such a person's radar rarely leads to anything good, and the mods will need to intervene anyway

Comment: Unfortunately, mod response time is [a bit slow these days](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425115), due to [the strike](https://openletter.mousetail.nl), @ErikA. :-) To be clear: that is not meant as discouragement from raising flags. We have every intention of dealing with the flags after the strike is over, and we wish we were able to handle them now. Just set your expectations appropriately. And realize there may be value in posting comments now, in order to warn your fellow users, when you would not have done so under normal circumstances when SO's legendary moderation is in play.

Comment: I think you already did the right thing by warning the asker in comments that it might be a chatgpt answer, but letting the asker decide what to do, just in case it ends up helping him. As for the guy's downvotes to you, if this is a case of [serial downvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed), it will eventually get automatically reverted by the website. In case he starts harassing you by doing this again and again, he will get flagged in the system so that a human can look into him