# Downvotes and false accusations of using ChatGPT: how do I handle it?

Tags: discussion, comments, downvotes, chatgpt

I am a new contributor who joined yesterday. I have answered some questions, but some people accused me of using ChatGPT when answering questions. I take the time to read the documentation and I give answers based on my knowledge and experience. However, I use Grammarly to create an excellent verbal answer.

We talked and I said that I am not using any AI or GPT. Afterwards, I received downvotes on all my answers (I have answered 5 questions so far).

**What should I do in this situation and how am I supposed to react?**

Comment: I use Grammarly extensively, if your contributions appear to be generated by ChatGPT, it’s not due to the use of Grammarly.

Comment: Relevant deleted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76681081

Comment: “Based on your configuration, it seems that you …”, “If I understand correctly what you're attempting to accomplish” and “let me explain the steps” - Starting answers off with statements like that are almost exclusively used by ChatGPT.

Comment: Regrettably, the community taking matters into its own hands, with inaccurate public accusations and downvotes based on them, is the inevitable result of [restricting moderators from moderating AI-generated content](/q/425000). The moderator team is _extremely_ experienced at identifying AI-generated content, and can handle suspected cases discretely without making a public fuss like has happened in this case. Here, I believe you: [edit: most of] your answers don't read like ChatGPT. If the community could rely on us again for moderation of AI content, this sort of thing wouldn't happen.

Comment: What should I do now, how am I supposed to share my answers and is there any steps or documentation to follow? To avoid being considered as chatgpt which am not using . Look example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76675995/symfony-jwt-the-requested-url-was-not-found-on-this-server/76678796#76678796

Comment: @ChafikKerboute - I gave you some honest helpful feedback.

Comment: My 2cts, but the "writing/answering style" + the "thinking process" for answering (+ layout/formatting/spelling/grammar) of the 6 Answers I checked is completely different (3 styles), I would "smell a fish" also...

Comment: re: "_I use Grammarly to create an excellent verbal answer._" - How is it that you use Grammarly and still have things like "iIt", uncapitalized sentences, and a sentence which just says "the."?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen note: editing ChatGPT answers is not a new thing. Not that I'm 100% convinced that that's what's happening here, but it's a possibility.

Comment: Yep, following on my previous Comment, I reviewed (and analyzed) all 6 Answers "a bit deeper", and all the 5 first ones are "definitely 'ChatGPT'-generated" for me, sorry @RyanM... No exception, #6 is "human" and was posted after this current Qt on 'Meta'. // In reverse order, #1 and #4 are pretty obvious due to the formatting, #2 is pretty "impressive": Full Script posted from 10 vague Reqs in 6 min!! Positive point about #1, the grammar is perfect, even the (incorrect) "*there's + [Plural]*" in a Comment in this Thread has been correctly converted to "there are + [Plural]", ah-ah...!

Comment: @RyanM-Regenerateresponse forgive my skepticism on that point... The moderator community can, of course, deal with such situations discretely as you have the tools to do so.  But, while I don't wish to call your personal skills into question, the suggestion that the moderator community across the SE estate are all highly experienced in this and more capable seems a "bold" claim. I know that moderators have received training on this, but the suggestion that being voted in as a moderator makes you better at this detection comes off as arrogant and incorrect.

Comment: @chivracq Different questions ask for different answer styles. There's nothing fishy about that. Also I've never seen AI-generated links to pictures, which are definitely not up to our formatting standards but at least demonstrate some human writing action.

Comment: @Bergi, yeah, I would agree, of course, ... but hum, review "a bit deeper" by yourself the 5 first Answers, and you will "smell that fish", ah-ah...!

Comment: @chivracq I see nothing but a newbie who doesn't know formatting best practices posting answers in their favourite topic, symfony. Most likely copy-pasting bits and pieces (and screenshots) from their current own project. Sure, using boldface instead of monospace font for code snippets is also common in ChatGPT answers, but other telltale signs (phrases, repetition, flawless grammar) are missing. This is not a clear-cut case, you should assume good faith.

Comment: Your answers don't seem like ChatGPT / AI generated to me. There seem to be some signs on some of them but looking closer that just seems to be your writing style. There are / were some issues with your downvoted answers though, I won't attribute the votes there to the ChatGPT accusations. To list a few problems: Images of code, faulty / insecure code (the SQL injection), answer with code and little to no explanation, things like "I hope that helps" in the answer, etc.

Comment: @Bergi, "*you should assume good faith*", that was completely my "starting-point" when I went checking the 6 Answers, I actually/honestly wanted to "prove" OP was right and "defend" them, with "my arguments"..., except that my "Analysis" actually convinced me of the opposite... Yep, some bits have been adapted, C&P'ed in some Editor that changed the Capitalizing just like when Staff posted all the Technologies for the 2023 Survey, and on the bits "adapted" no 'Grammarly' was applied anymore... Strange...!?

Comment: I don't know whether you use ChatGPT or not, and honestly in your particular case I don't even think it's relevant. In general your answers are very vague and broad and not specific enough on what is asked and any downvotes may be just due to that fact.

Comment: @PhilipCouling single moderator might be more or less experienced. But the main leverage is that they are **team**. They share tools, experience and opinions.

Comment: @PhilipCouling Moderators are in better position to judge whether something is ChatGPT or not as they also have access to post history we don't have. They have seen far more ChatGPT posts and that increases the ability to recognize them with more confidence. That does not that each individual mod is superb in doing that as this is skill that can vary between individuals, but they can discuss about less obvious cases.

Comment: "The moderator team is extremely experienced at identifying AI-generated content, and can handle suspected cases discretely without making a public fuss like has happened in this case." Very pretentious thing to think. Too bad such grand talent cannot be spent on determining whether an answer is actually useful or not, rather than arguing about what tool was used to generate it

Comment: I don't see a word lied in that statement. The moderating team has had to deal with this nonsense for a long time now so of course they're experienced. Experienced does not imply bulletproof, it means "better at it than inexperienced people". And it is also very true that the average visitor who should be curating content only tends to make a big mess out of trying to moderate the actions of people. You can't do a good job when you don't have access to the tools to do so, so it ends up being targeted voting and not-so-classy comments.

Comment: @user13267 determining whether answer is AI generated or not is faster that determining whether answer is accurate and the former does not require expertise in the particular technology stack. Moderators can successfully and promptly moderate AI based answers, but they would never be able to do that based on accuracy as they would have to be domain experts to do that. Also there is not enough regular users to successfully moderate based on accuracy for non AI content, let alone AI one.

Comment: And to @DalijaPrasnikar's point is one of the main reasons why the strike is occurring.  SE has said that mods can only take action if they judge the *content* to be low-quality.  And that's simply not something that can scale to the number of posts here on SO with the number of Mods (at any level).  With the present level of LLM technology, along with the drastic *misuse* of it here, they simply have to assume that any AI-use is bad AI-use.

Comment: @user13267 Further, we're a site built on *reputation* and trust.  Folks posting AI-generated answers, even if the answers are *correct* are not demonstrating that *they*, the person themselves, have expertise in the technology being discussed.  Are you upvoting the AI or are you upvoting the user?  [Further reading](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389675/902710).

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I was responding to words in [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425562/downvotes-and-false-accusations-of-using-chatgpt-how-do-i-handle-it?noredirect=1#comment965507_425562) where those words do not speak of **tools** but **extreme experience**. Discussion of tools is fine, but claiming moderators Arne personally more capable is arrogant.

Comment: @PhilipCouling if you think they have extra tools for dealing with AI, you are mistaken. It is in fact experience based.

Comment: @PhilipCouling I was talking about same comment. The more AI posts you see the more easily can you spot them and moderators had to deal and have seen far more SI posts than regular users. There is nothing arrogant about it. It is a matter of experience. Also the "tools" I mentioned are not AI detection tools, but access to users complete posting history which regular users don't have.

Comment: Many comments here seem only tangential to the question unless one believes that no false positives exists. Could "some people accused me of using ChatGPT" please be more specified? In what way were you accused of using ChatGPT? In comments? Something else? What did they say exactly?

Comment: @PhilipCouling That we have a lot of "experience" is simply a fact.  It means that we have done it a lot, because [we have](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389844/165261). You can think that we're bad at it despite that experience, but it is a fact that we have a lot of experience.  Note that I'm only referring to the Stack Overflow moderation team; not all network sites have been hit as hard as Stack Overflow with AI content. I can tell you that the tools I've tried *are* bad: they don't understand what they're reading any more than the AI generating it does, so they can't tell reliably.

Comment: Additionally, I never said that our expertise comes magically from being elected: we have private chatrooms where we share knowledge, experience, and advice between each other and with various members of the community. Most of the ChatGPT flags were being handled by the handful of moderators who've handled more of them in the past, other than for very obvious cases that any of us can identify easily. Decisions that are appealed are reviewed for error. Whatever you think of our moderation, we put a *lot* of time and thought into it.

Comment: @RyanM-Regenerateresponse I don't think you are bad. It's the inference that you are better that everyone else. Your words infer that nobody has that experience but you. And again that is both arrogant and incorrect. Remember there are other routes to acquire such experience that don't involve being a mod for SE. And I don't think that experience is ubiquitous across the SE estate either. I've observed some very talented mods here on SO yet I've also encountered some who are less so across SE.

Comment: @PhilipCouling My point was merely that the _typical case_ is that a moderator flag will reach someone with considerably more experience (consider that the median ChatGPT flag is probably handled by someone who's made _thousands_ of such calls) than the typical user in the comments. Of course, there are many non-mods with similar experience levels on the site, many of whom have been instrumental in assisting the moderator team with finding AI content. And again, I'm only referring to the Stack Overflow moderators (though mods on any site can easily consult with us and other community experts).

Comment: @RyanM-Regenerate-response yes I understood your point. I would be tempted to agree but for two problematic issues. Firstly: experience doesn't necessarily lead to better success rate. Without concrete evidence feeding back to you on your own success there's a serious risk that it will only make you a very experienced which hunter. Sadly, not one mod has been able to explain to me how they know they are getting it right and that's a problem. Secondly your choice of words was loose. It's as much your choice of words that I take issue with as your point. With that I've said my piece.

Answer (score 34):

If you're *truly* getting downvotes because the voters think you're using ChatGPT and you really are not using it, then I'd just keep chugging along doing what you're doing. If what you are writing is useful to people, they will upvote it, and in the long term, that will probably offset the downvotes. Those who are acting in good faith and sincerely believe you are using ChatGPT and have downvoted for that reason will not (because they should not) downvote other content that you have written without cause.

If you really want to do a better job at writing posts here, based on what I see you've written, you should take a look at the following:

- /help/formatting
- [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541)
- [What should I keep out of my posts and titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011/997587)

That being said, I personally have a hard time trusting you. For one thing, you claim that you "*use Grammarly to create an excellent verbal answer*", but I have observed several basic grammar and spelling errors in your posts, and one of your currently undeleted posts has a signature ChatGPT format (I've seen enough ChatGPT answers to have alarm bells going off whenever I see it). And the fact that your response to a comment saying that one of your answers reads like ChatGPT is ["*what if it's not a gpt answer ?*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76680933/76681081#comment135191726_76681081) just feels... weird to me. I'm not going to read into those things deeply. I personally am not confident enough to say that I think your content is from ChatGPT, but I *am* suspicious.

Comment: "*I personally have a hard time trusting you.*", yep agreed, see the [Comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425562#comment965527_425562) I posted on the Question at the exact same time (same second!) like you/this Answer.

Comment: I have hard time trusting the OP, too. I haven't looked at all the answers but the second one I opened was clear as day that it is ChatGPT.

Comment: As of the time this question was posted, the one deleted answer and one of the five undeleted ones read as *possible* ChatGPT (with human modifications).  (I would've said "most of your answers" in my comment on the question, but I'd have exceeded the character limit...).  The rest don't really.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar can you accept that without a single mechanism to provide accurate feedback to you when you misclassify, this leaves you (and us all) worryingly prone to confirmation bias. Little dopamine hits every time we ***think*** we caught a liar but with no hard evidence to confirm one way or the other.  The apparent (over) confidence is an extremely worrying trend that can only lead to "which hint".

Comment: @PhilipCouling that mechanism would be the mods and flag rejection messages / chat rooms I think. And if someone gets content delete or a mod warning for ChatGPT reasons, they can appeal using the contact form.

Comment: @PhilipCouling Like starball said, there is a feedback through how our flags are handled (personally, I have 0 rejections and all flagged posts were removed). And when it comes to mods, Ryan M gave good overview of the process.

Comment: \**[witch hunt](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/witch-hunt#Noun)*. Closest: *"3. (by extension) A public or political campaign or investigation which smears a person or group."*

Comment: @PeterMortensen I don't quite get what you are trying to say. Or maybe you you were replying to a comment invoking "witch hunt" (which is deleted now) or something?

Answer (score 12):

I have seen a lot of different responses about the topic of using AI here. As far as I understand it (and correct me if I am wrong) using ChatGPT (and other similar generative AIs such as LLMs) for writing questions or answers (fully or partially) is temporarily banned. I don't think the problem would inherently be that someone is using an LLM but rather someone is violating an explicit SO policy. As a sidenote, using AI in general is not forbidden, in fact Grammarly (which does use AI to some degree) is allowed. The issue is not with AI in general but it is with LLMs in particular being against SO policy for now.

Personally I believe that in many cases the downvotes in your answers were warranted, not because you were using ChatGPT. I don't know if you did use it or not and honestly I don't think that is relevant for the downvotes to make sense. I think your answers were generic and were written without considering the specifics of the question. For a specific example: [Swiper Element doesn't swipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76683124/swiper-element-doesnt-swipe/76683349#76683349) you mention:

> It might be due to misconfiguration of your swiper, let me explain the steps you need to follow in order to achieve a swiper that swipes.

and then list the steps one must take to configure it. However the user provided their code on exactly how they are using swiper. Your answer does not specify where in their code the misconfiguration is happening and how they can modify their code to correct it. If you need more information on how something was implemented you need to ask for clarification from the user rather than assume what the problem *may* be and respond so broadly. This makes this answer bad and the downvotes justified. Other answers that people are flagging as ChatGPT generated also have this particular problem of being overly general so even if you did write them with no ChatGPT help (again AI help with grammar is not really a problem) they still have quality problems that can result to justified downvotes.

Also beware [the meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect). Asking this question, and given the quality problems of your existing answers, it is very likely you get many more downvotes than if you didn't actually say anything. As another user noted, if you really think you're unfairy accused of using ChatGPT to generate answers and believe the downvotes are due to that then the actual solution is not to write a question in meta about it but try to figure out why your answers look ChatGPT generated and how you can write better answers moving forward. I already mentioned something you can do which I think will make your anwers much better quality.

Comment: thank you so much for this clarified answer, and the advices really appreciate it.

Comment: I cannot foot stomp this answer more, I have submitted thousands of answers, and every single one has been written with the aid of Grammarly. In my case the only language I know is English, so I will repeat my original comment, the use of Grammarly absolutely isn’t the reason users believe your using ChatGPT or any similar LLM to generate answers. The problems with the answers, as described in this answer, are legitimate. Deleting them absolutely shouldn’t be considered. The problems should be addressed. By deleting them you will just make it impossible to upvote them.

Comment: @SecurityHound No not just that. It will also make it impossible to downvote them. A strong counterargument from the perspective of a person who's content is receiving downvotes.

Comment: @Gimby - Deleting poorly received contributions typically only results in one thing, the contributor, being prevented from submitting new contributions. In this particular case, the authors contributions, are getting significantly worse since they asked about their contributions. Which raises new questions for me.

Comment: @SecurityHound The "getting significantly worse" is "explained" because the user said they were giving up the use of Grammarly due to accusations.  Whether or not this is a sufficient explanation is a different question that I'll skip for now.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds - No, it’s more like answers are now clearly written by the author but still have significant issues and I am not talking about grammar or spelling issues. For instance submitting an answer, which appears correct, but then making a comment suggesting they don’t know what something was and if someone did they should comment. I don’t care enough to fact check their newest answer only that I recognize it has problems

Comment: Looking at that specific answer, after performing a more in-depth analysis of the described problem and the solution suggested, I wouldn’t find the answer to be helpful. This is an answer that clearly was written by the author, it being problematic, has to do with the accuracy of the code not easily resolved grammatical errors that might or might not exist

Answer (score 11):

I have only checked a handful of your posts and haven't done any analysis, so I can only be suspicious, but won't raise any accusations (although others who have done some analyses may do so).

Regardless of the fact whether you are posting gpt answers or not, your answers are lacking quality. I suggest taking some time to familiarize yourself with the site you want to contribute to. It may take quite a while before you feel comfortable but don't get disappointed and try not to get frustrated by downvotes. If you wish, delete your downvoted answers (don't overdo it since it can lead to [an answer ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th/255584#255584) as pointed out in the comments), but learn from your mistakes. Read the comments. Look at other questions and answers. Follow their formatting, mimic their language, etc. You may learn a thing or two.

I have asked some bad questions and posted bunch of low-quality answers. In some cases, I went back years later, when I knew better, and edited them to be better. In other instances, I deleted them altogether. I have found more questions to answer and asked more questions later on.

Also, listen to Kevin's advice: Do not engage.

Comment: deleting the downvoted answers will contribute to an answer ban. Instead of doing that, I'd encourage to _improve_ the downvoted answers. Same guidance is in [the FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255584/11107541): "_Note the emphasis on fixing. Do not delete your posts. \[...\] Deleting your posts does not help to lift the ban. Only fixing does!_"

Comment: I can agree that onboarding is a problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342788/997587 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364572/997587 cover that. sadly the onboarding project seems dead. There's only so much the community can do about that. The company needs to step up and do something to improve systematic onboarding.

Answer (score 9):

Regardless of whether the answers are GPT, making accusations in comments and taking other retaliatory actions against individual users is not a productive or correct way of handling these situations. *The user should have raised a flag and moved on.* I would advise anyone being falsely accused in comments of using GPT to similarly raise a flag and not engage.

The response to this meta question has been ridiculous.

Comment: I fully support the moderator strike, but it shouldn't come as a surprise that people start resorting to vigilante justice when GPT flags aren't being handled for a month and a half and counting.

Comment: I agree, it isn’t surprising, but it also isn’t right. It’s rude and directly against the rules here.

Comment: It's genuinely unclear to me what exactly you find ridiculous here?

Comment: Maybe it will serve as a reminder to the company that an imperfect enforcement of the law is better than lawlessness.

Comment: To note: [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425550/what-to-do-if-a-user-initiates-a-downvote-war-because-ive-been-pointing-out-tha#comment965414_425550) by Cody Gray, where I pretty much take the same point, but Cody notes that due to the strike delays in handling flags are long, and it may be sensible to leave a comment to alert others

Comment: @KevinB Your assertion that pointing out via comments when an answer looks like GPT is *"rude and against the rules"* seems overly broad.  I do it *a lot* myself, and I attempt to make the comments as nice as possible.  There's always the chance that I'm wrong, so I try to give the user the benefit of the doubt, even when there's no doubt in my mind :-).  I even checked with a moderator before I started posting them, who recommended some of the wording I use.  So I *know* it's not against the rules based on moderator guidance, and I do my *best* to make sure it's not rude.

Comment: I've even had an SE community manager reach out to me via one of the mods to check on some of my comments, asking why I thought certain content was AI-based.  After I explained the reasoning (it was what we would *all* know to be GPT, but it was hard to find out of the user's 20+ answers), there was never any question again ;-).  And never any mention even from the SE *employee* that my actions were rude or against the rules.

Comment: Adding a comment that an answer appears to be chatGPT is not only *not* rude but it's essential. It at least gives future readers a chance to be alerted that the answer might be convincing nonsense rather than the product of genuine expertise.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds i've seen many of your comments, and i agree that they're certainly not as rude/non-constructive as many of the ones that have been posted here.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks.  I do try.  Honestly, I'm not a fan of the bold in my comments, since I usually equate that with "yelling", but the  Mod who reworded it felt strongly that that part should be bolded to stand out so that it would be the first thing potential readers see.