# Current position on & proposal for the responsible use of AI on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, chatgpt

The current policies of Stack Overflow around the responsible use of AI are confusing and unclear, both for moderators and users. There was the old announcement that as a [temporary policy any use of GPT of ChatGPT was prohibited](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned), which to me sounded like a blanket ban, even for responsible AI use, and there is the [official SO statement on posting GPT generated answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy), which by my reading referred more to posting unverified, inaccurate GPT generated answers and to plain copy & paste practices. In addition, there have been announcements to moderators mentioning that due to the [high false positive rate, GPT use cannot be accurately detected & hence that the policy against the use of GPT would & should no longer be enforced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389928/gpt-on-the-platform-data-actions-and-outcomes). At the same time, I experienced myself that when I tried to post a [well verified answer mentioning the use of ChatGPT 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48119360/performant-2d-sdl-or-opengl-graphics-in-r-for-fast-display-of-raster-image-using/76472961?noredirect=1#comment134865427_76472961) (where ChatGPT 4 was used produce a small part of the SDL+OpenGL code & not even any of the text of my answer or the benchmarking & output that I showed) it was instantly removed by moderators (this happened repeatedly) (my answer is available on GitHub [here](https://github.com/coolbutuseless/nara/issues/7)). Official guidelines are that any source, including a particular AI, should be cited, but if one does that then one gets the answer immediately deleted or downvoted (as happened for my ChatGPT 4 assisted, but verified answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76925/ridge-regression-in-r-where-coefficients-are-penalized-toward-numbers-other-than)). Whilst poor, unverified answers for which GPT was used, but not disclosed, remain on the site, as are any other poor quality human-written answers.

There is also no official statement on whether code produced by GPT powered GitHub Copilot would be allowed (I would presume it is, but a blanket ban would suggest otherwise), or if [other generative AI can be used to help formulate a verified answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422949/are-all-generative-ais-banned) (e.g. Anthropic's [Claude+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_language_model#List_of_large_language_models)).

So what is the official position on the responsible use of AI on Stack Overflow?

To clarify my own position on this: I strongly disagree with a blanket ban on the use of AI-generated content and feel that responsible use should be allowed. A complete ban is not only impractical but also counterproductive. A more reasonable approach would be to implement measures that address the concerns associated with posting unverified or poor quality answers in quick succession, providing advice on how users should independently verify and refine AI-generated answers before posting them, and providing a good reward system for up- & downvoting of good & poor quality answers, so that the best, highest quality answers will always float to the top (currently that is not the case, e.g. for [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76925/ridge-regression-in-r-where-coefficients-are-penalized-toward-numbers-other-than) the ChatGPT 4-based answer is by far the most correct & detailed one, but received no more votes than the other answers).

Transparency is also crucial. Users should have the option to disclose if an answer was partially or fully generated by AI, and in fact are required to do so under current policies. Hence, they definitely should not be punished for being transparent about it.

I have personally experienced the benefits of using GPT in solving complex problems and providing accurate answers. In some cases, where specialized knowledge was required or existing answers fell short, GPT was instrumental in delivering valuable insights. For instance, it assisted me in optimizing code performance, provided [correct R to Rcpp translations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73811835/faster-way-to-calculate-the-hessian-fisher-information-matrix-of-a-nnetmulti), wrote correct, working code from scratch and even suggested solutions with complete mathematical proofs. Especially the performance of the paid version, ChatGPT 4 (potentially with plugins such as [WolframAlpha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WolframAlpha) for mathematical work or the ScholarAI plugin to provide citations) is impressive and in my view on a par with the quality of most of the answers I see on SO, at least for the ones involving programming, and of course after formal verification and fixing some small bugs.

The argument against GPT often stems from concerns about reliability. However, it is essential to note that responsible users employ AI as a tool, not as a substitute for critical thinking and verification. Users must still ask the right questions, provide adequate context, and thoroughly review AI-generated responses. GPT serves as an aid in reaching correct answers faster, but the responsibility for vetting and testing lies with the user. It would also lower the bar for domain experts to post good answers, given that they might not have the time to write out a full, detailed answer on SO themselves, but might do so if they can be partly aided by ChatGPT or Claude+ to phrase their answer (this applies for example to [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76925/ridge-regression-in-r-where-coefficients-are-penalized-toward-numbers-other-than) where as a domain expert I knew the answer, but would not have been able to invest the time to write out such a detailed answer).

Moreover, it is worth considering the significant impact of GPT in the programming community. Many experienced programmers, including notable figures like [John Carmack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Carmack), rely on GPT daily for efficient problem-solving & 83% of all software developers state they now regularly use ChatGPT. The quality and relevance of GPT-generated answers often surpasses those found on Stack Overflow, which has led to a [decline in traffic to this site as well as to a decline in the rate of asking questions or providing answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389928/gpt-on-the-platform-data-actions-and-outcomes). [GPT detectors, both automated and human-based, have been found to be ineffective with high error rates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389928/gpt-on-the-platform-data-actions-and-outcomes). This means that any policy against the use of GPT or other AI platforms like Claude+ would also be unenforceable.

Rather than seeing GPT and other AI as a threat, we should embrace its potential to enhance problem-solving and knowledge sharing. Stack Overflow could benefit from archiving exceptional GPT-generated answers, particularly for questions that have remained unanswered or lacked satisfactory solutions. By upvoting accurate answers and incentivizing quality control, the community can maintain the reliability and integrity of the platform. Embracing the potential of GPT would not only improve the quality of answers, but also foster innovation and attract a diverse community of problem-solvers, thereby making sure that the Stack Overflow community will remain vibrant and active, and that no user should feel threatened for posting an answer that was even just in part inspired or enabled by the use of ChatGPT or other AI tools, which [going forward could just result in many users, including the most active ones, just leaving the site altogether](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389928/gpt-on-the-platform-data-actions-and-outcomes), which would be a great shame.

Comment: *... would be to implement measures that address the concerns associated with posting unverified or poor quality answers in quick succession ...*: What measures do you suggest and how would you enforce them?

Comment: @BDL Tighter restrictions for example on making posts in quick succession, especially if it would concern users with a poor record in terms of giving high quality, highly rated answers...

Comment: Neutral btw. ChatGPT is no different from a gun, telling people to use it responsibly isn't going to stop the mass shootings or the occasional toddler offing himself

Comment: @prusswan That's a bit of a poor comparison. I propose to not just tell people to use it responsibly, but to make sure that adequate reward systems are in place so that only high quality AI inspired answers would get upvoted. I.e. a much better reward system for up or downvoting for good or bad answers.

Comment: There are already pretty strict rules for posting many posts in succession, @TomWenseleers . It's only once you have over a certain rep threshold (can't remember what off the top of my head) that some of those are lowered.

Comment: There's (again) a lot of rambling and noise in your question here... You really need to be more specific in what you're suggesting or asking. As it is right now, this question is unclear.

Comment: The community and moderators' current position is very clear; I've marked this question as a duplicate of that very position/policy. You can also read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Comment: @TomWenseleers: I guess your post would be more productive if you add a suggestion for a concrete policy on AI usage and how exactly it should be implemented. To this point, there wasn't any good suggestion made that prevents AI copy-pasting while not harming the ability of human users to provide answers. I'm sure if you can come up with something good, that will be helpful for the community.

Comment: @CodyGray-onstrike Sorry but the post you link doesn't answer any of my questions. It mentions GPT. Does that also include Github Copilot? Does it also include Anthropic Claude+? RyanM-Regenerateresponse mentioned my specific question was ruled to be legit & would be allowed. Yet it gets deleted. That shows the level of confusion there is on what rules are in place.

Comment: The [official policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy) is ___very___ clear in that ___no___ GPT-generated content is allowed whatsoever: _"to issue immediate suspensions of up to 30 days to users who are copying and pasting GPT content onto the site"_

Comment: Yes, it includes all GPT-generated content.

Comment: @RyanM-Regenerateresponse told me otherwise yesterday... And if I had used Anthropic Claude+ it would have been OK? And if I had not disclosed that for part of the answer (not the benchmarking or actual answer) I had used ChatGPT4 it would have been OK too?

Comment: ChatGPT4 is still GPT, @TomWenseleers . The ruling isn't against GPT-3, it's against GPT (Generative pre-trained transformer). ChatGPT and Co-Pilot both use GPT.

Comment: No, that's not what Ryan told you. He didn't give an "okay" to GPT in general, he told you your specific answer was being left undeleted while they figure it out: _"For the record, it's been decided to leave that particular answer up, at least for the time being. This is unrelated to whether it explicitly admits the source is ChatGPT, to be clear. In general, we do expect sources to be cited, including AI. The exact policy is in flux; as this policy notes in the title, it is temporary."_

Comment: "Anthropic Claude" ___is___ a LLM. It ___is___ A GTP implementation. It ___does___ fall under that same rule. ___ALL___ AI-driven text generators do. How is that so hard to understand?

Comment: @ThomA Performance is massively different though. And it says nothing about other LLMs like Anthropic's Claude+ e.g.... So pretty clear that the current guidelines are unclear & open to interpretation.

Comment: It's a blanket ban on any and all things GPT. ___It's not that difficult!___

Comment: That doesn't matter, @TomWenseleers . If I go to road where bicycles are banned, I can't say "but I'm fast on a bicycle, so it's ok". The same applies here; GPT is GPT and GPT is banned,

Comment: @Cerbrus Sorry but nobody counts Anthropic Claude, Google Bard, Meta's LLama and Google's PaLM2 as all falling under GPT - yes they use transformers, but OpenAI has ruled that GPT should be regarded as a brand of OpenAI.

Comment: Yea, you're wrong. [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_pre-trained_transformer) is not a copyrighted term. OpenAI might be the market leader, but they don't (and can't) own that abbreviation.

Comment: @ThomA The net result will just be that users will keep on using them to assist them in answering questions or parts of questions, but will not disclose it, and that nothing can be done about it, as GPT cannot be accurately detected & so the policy cannot be enforced, while well-meaning users like myself that would be transparent about their sources would get punished for it. Quite a ridiculous & a pretty bad outcome I would say...

Comment: Then suggest something that fixes that problem.

Comment: @Cerbrus My suggestions on this (e.g. a better reward system to flag correct & incorrect answers) were above, but the question got closed down. Anyway, gotta get on with my work. That SO sorts it out, not my job!

Comment: `You're the one making a suggestion. If you want your suggestion to get any traction, you're going to have to be clear. As I stated before, this question is vague, rambling, unclear.

Comment: @TomWenseleers: Stating "we need a better rewards system" is not a concrete suggestion. How would a better system look like, which changes to our current system does it require? Which impacts will it have to the current state of working?

Comment: As a professor, SMART formulation should ring a bell. Use it.

Comment: Well sorry after all the effort I spent already I can't be asked to go and edit a question that's now been closed for being a duplicate for already having an answer: it's not allowed. I am a professor, yes, and I have work to do. Asking that AI assisted answers would present reproducible code with a benchmark would be easy enough to check that answers are verified. That was obviously the case for the answers I posted there. It's not rocket science. And SO will sort it out - they are well aware of the problems with current policies... We don't need those protracted debates on meta SO for that.

Comment: ___Again___ you're the one that wants to make a suggestion, it's ___your___ responsibility to make the suggestion credible and understandable. You are in no place to complain about this getting closed when you continually disregard any and all advice given. You're repeatedly stated _"SO will sort it out"_... That's not good enough.

Comment: "Sorry but the post you link doesn't answer any of my questions. It mentions GPT. Does that also include Github Copilot? Does it also include Anthropic Claude+?" - see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422949, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412696, etc.

Comment: Well, at least I think I discovered the reason why traffic to Stack Overflow is declining so much (https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=today%205-y&q=stackoverflow&hl=en) & ChatGPT is booming (https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=today%205-y&q=chatgpt&hl=en). It might have to do something with the fact that on the latter you can actually ask questions & get helpful replies without being shouted at by an angry mob of unbearable users & moderators. :-)

Comment: If chat GPT answers the question, why post at Stackoverflow at all? If it can answer the simple stuff and eliminate the duplicates, that's a huge benefit to Stackoverflow. Yes, SO page views will go way down. I don't really have a problem with that because people should come here when they can't easily find the information they need elsewhere. If someone comes up with a better way to access and distribute the information in SO's database, cool beans! My one fear is self-perpetuating circle-jerks of bad information because a language model wouldn't know a bad idea if it got bit by one.

Comment: I see the nature of programming changing dramatically with AI picking up a lot of the scut work much like compilers, databases, and RAD tools once did. A robot that can take a description of program behaviour and turn it into a executable program really isn't that much different from a compiler anyway. Someone has to describe the program. Someone has to verify that the program does what it says on the box., nothing more and nothing less. If the robot does everything else, groovy. More time with the kids.

Comment: @user4581301 For me it now has become the opposite actually: ChatGPT4 allows me to solve even the more complex problems that I never got an answer to on Stack Overflow, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48119360/performant-2d-sdl-or-opengl-graphics-in-r-for-fast-display-of-raster-image-using, https://github.com/coolbutuseless/nara/issues/7 (the human written answer seems to hallucinate a solution there). Which is why I would still like a means to publicly preserve those answer (after verification, with reproducible code & benchmarks given).

Comment: @user4581301 Also this answer, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76925/ridge-regression-in-r-where-coefficients-are-penalized-toward-numbers-other-than - that of ChatGPT4 is a million times better than any of the other answers. And for me that's now more the rule than the exception. Maths capabilities, incl with Wolfram Alpha plugin, now also rock, cf benchmarks here https://arxiv.org/abs/2306.08997

Comment: @user4581301 Posts like https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/38220/why-is-chatgpt-bad-at-math that I see here are terribly outdated with respect to the true capabilities and accuracy of ChatGPT4. I would like to see objective up to date benchmarks of the accuracy of ChatGPT4 vs Stack Overflow answers using the latest version... Soon it will be the case that if ChatGPT can't answer your question no one on SO will either...

Comment: Come on, sir. You should well know that my single datapoint can beat up your single datapoint. But you've misread me. We're effectively arguing the same point. I'm just going further: If the new tool can out-perform Stackoverflow, let Stackoverflow die.

Comment: @user4581301 Well, call me nostalgic, but I would prefer that Stack Overflow would stay around actually. But my argument is that at some point in the future they'll have to start embracing AI if they want it to stay relevant. It will not be the case that Stack Overflow will only still get the difficult questions which will then be answered. Those questions will be too much work to answer for any regular human that can't be assisted by any AI tool.

Comment: I expect that that Stackoverflow will still be in the background fielding the new-and-interesting stuff, but it'll stop being the general-purpose helpdesk that's racking up most of the pageviews. In a way, AI could be an Eternal September mitigation tool. And not because it exterminated mankind. Side note: SO generally isn't all that good at answering big questions. Difficult questions, yes, but big questions are almost always many small problems ganging up on you. If the AI can aggregate multiple small answers to small problems into a larger solution, that's significant value add.

Comment: They also need to work on GPT's tendency to make shit up when it can't find a correct answer. I don't know is a valid response to any question. Not on Stackoverflow, mind you. Here if you don't actually know the answer you're expected to post nothing.

Comment: @user4581301 Well, I also see plenty of plain wrong answers on SO - like the one posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48119360/performant-2d-sdl-or-opengl-graphics-in-r-for-fast-display-of-raster-image-using, which I would call a human hallucination of an answer/solution. ChatGPT4 got quite a bit better on that - it will also sometimes say it doesn't know or doesn't have the info. But then again it knows a hell of a lot, more than any individual human alive today....

Comment: i mean, you can say that as many times as you want, until results exist outside of your miraculously positive results that noone else can verify it is meaningless. Instead, we can continue to act on the results we *have* seen, repeatedly, for the past 6-8 months.

Comment: @KevinB My results are perfectly in line with all the latest benchmarks of ChatGPT4, e.g. for maths, https://arxiv.org/abs/2306.08997, answering BAR exam questions, LSAT, SAT, etc (top 10% relative to avg human capability). I presume you still get too many unverified ChatGPT3.5 answers. But a simple guideline "any posted code that makes use of code partially or completely based on ChatGPT output should show the output & reproducible benchmarks" would solve that... From all the negative comments on ChatGPT on this site I get the distinct impression no one spent more than 5 mins with it.

Comment: @TomWenseleers None of those align with what we see here on stack sites. Until they do, they are irrelevant to how AI is to be managed here.

Comment: @KevinB Presumably because it's unedited, unverified ChatGPT3.5 answers - that one just scored in the bottom 10% on university entrance exams. Meanwhile ChatGPT4 scores in the top 10% - that's an entirely different kettle of fish, especially also for programming & maths. In any case: checking if an answer is correct is 10x easier than checking if GPT has been used if not disclosed. In the case of my question taken down by those moderators: the output was included, so I obviously ran & tested the code.

Comment: That's fine, however, people are still using the old crap if that's what they're still using. It doesn't change the stance or how it should be handled here.

Comment: If it's truely as good as you think it is, It has no purpose here and people who use it have no reason to share it here outside of earning imaginary internet points on skills they don't have.

Comment: @KevinB But again - when it comes to programming related answers - a simple guideline "code that was produced partially or completely using ChatGPT or Github Copilot should be disclosed as such and should show output & reproducible benchmarks to demonstrate that it works" would solve that... Bad code produced by GPT can be taken care of in the same way as bad code produced by any human...

Comment: Bad code and good code alike has no place here if it was generated by AI. If people want an AI answer they can go to a site that provides that service.

Comment: @KevinB With respect to that last point - I disagree - in my case I decided to paste in an answer after finally having managed to solve my original problem with the help of ChatGPT4, after 5 years - and I felt that was of interest to the SO community - being able to do fast graphics in R is of general interest. Many would reason like that. If they would occasionally see an unanswered question that they finally found the answer to, they would likely paste in their code... But not if they would get banned for doing so or have their answer immediately deleted...

Comment: @KevinB The argument "if people want to use ChatGPT4 why would they bother going to SO anyway, then they could ask it directly" I also don't buy - it can still take some prompts to get the answer right, and then having a single canonical answer compiled from a number of prompts with reproducible & verified working code is valuable & could still save other people some work...

Comment: If you understand the code enough to provide an answer, then you are answering it as yourself, not AI, using knowledge that you yourself own. If you are copy pasting an answer that isn't yours, you aren't proving that you have that knowledge and that you are worthy of verifying its accuracy.

Comment: Don't forget, you have the knowledge/expertise to critique generated content, most people using GPT for generating code don't. That analysis is really important, so while it works great in isolation for folks like yourself, it just doesn't scale. Or at least so far it doesn't look like it's scaled well on SO

Comment: @KevinB Well of course I still understand code coming out of ChatGPT - most people would. But in my case I didn't want to read two books on OpenGL & SDL first to get my simple problem solved, so that part of the code came from ChatGPT, nicely annotated, https://github.com/coolbutuseless/nara/issues/7. But according to you the only mistake I made then was disclosing I had used ChatGPT4. I don't think that's fair, because here it literally just took me 2 prompts, so it seemed fair to mention it... And sources need to be given...

Comment: @KevinB Now the only consequence of Stack Overflow's policies is that that question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48119360/performant-2d-sdl-or-opengl-graphics-in-r-for-fast-display-of-raster-image-using/76472961?noredirect=1#comment134865427_76472961 will probably never receive an answer. Except for a human answer with a hallucinated solution...

Comment: @TomWenseleers You're free to use your expertise to answer it if you're so inclined, as is anyone else.

Comment: @KevinB But I've seen that being discussed too - some argue that if the level of prompting required to get an answer is high enough that in that case you own the code & answer & that the AI shouldn't be credited. That would be fine for me too, if that would be stated as such somewhere. But that would not be a blanket ban. And that would probably also allow for code produced whilst being assisted by Github Copilot and such...

Comment: Every premise of your question has been debunked here on MSO so many times and in so many ways already. Just read through the questions about it and the replies. chatGPT answers don't add value to the site, they are a huge net negative. The mere possibility that a few answers might not be so bad is hardly worth trading for the certainty that almost all will be convincing garbage.

Comment: @KevinB Well I've tried to paste in an answer three times already, but the mere disclosure that that bit of OpenGL+SDL code was ChatGPT4 generated was enough to get the answer deleted by a moderator. Really ridiculous! I could try once more, rephrasing my own answer once more & giving the ChatGPT4 code variable names a different name or something stupid like that, but honestly - at that point I give up...

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I have read all those replies yes, and I couldn't agree with any of them. It was just opinionated answers, without concrete data to back up any claims (e.g. data comparing the accuracy of ChatGPT4 answers vs Stack Overflow answer) & showcasing a complete unwillingness to even consider the most basic of policies like requiring posting reproducible, working code. These concerns I do share though https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389928/gpt-on-the-platform-data-actions-and-outcomes

Comment: On that Hallucination answer, that is an odd case. Typically the question gets dragged up by the quality of the answers. I see 43 upvotes on the question, suggesting it s a good question many would like to see answered. A net 1 upvote on the answer suggesting that the good karma of the question has not followed through and it's not all that good an answer. Maybe even a terrible answer. Too far out of my wheelhouse to be able to say for sure. One thing I know is that people don't like downvoting answers because it costs them (The PAIN!) one rep, so bad answers rarely get the deserved rating.

Comment: But this is all observational. Neither side has data that convinces the other, and it might not exist for a few more years. And by then the technologies will have evolved and need reassessing. I *hate* moving targets.

Comment: @user4581301 And yes that one "answer" there is now should at most have been a bad comment with a non-working solution. Much like ChatGPT4 having a bad day. :-)

Comment: @user4581301 I also thought that downvoting only happens in extreme cases, for extremely bad answers. But some users & moderators seem to be happy to spend some of their reputation to downvote answers merely because they mention GPT, even if they are well verified, and include benchmarks & if practically the whole answer is human written. Even if it's a perfect answer. Just out of principle. Like that annoying bureaucrat in the city hall that will tell you "the rules are the rules".

Comment: @user4581301 And yes the question has a fair few votes because it is widely applicable (many would be interested in fast graphics in R) & I gave it 5 bounties over the past 5 years. Now posted my answer here https://github.com/coolbutuseless/nara/issues/7 because moderators keep on finding it necessary to delete it on SO (3x now), merely because of me being transparent about the fact that a small bit of the code I show had been written by ChatGPT4 (not the benchmarks or the rest of the code). Complete insanity.

Comment: @TomWenseleers - It’s trivial to identify OpenAI generated output, to say otherwise, is factually incorrect. I just spend 2 hours trying to get Bard to generate code for me, not once was the code correct, it fully understood what I wanted since I verified it understood what a TLE was. AI generated trash is trash.

Comment: @SecurityHound There is no way in the world that you would have noticed that the OpenGL+SDL code in my answer (now posted at https://github.com/coolbutuseless/nara/issues/7) had been written by ChatGPT4 unless I had told you. If I would have done it myself it would have looked exactly the same. With minor effort any AI detector can be fooled. At 50% detection threshold the HuggingFace GPT detector has a false pos rate of 1 in 5 for pre-ChatGPT era SO posts...

Comment: @TomWenseleers - I did the first time you submitted it. I don’t need to use a AI detector.

Comment: @SecurityHound For this answer (which was an almost direct copy & paste ChatGPT4 answer), https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76925/ridge-regression-in-r-where-coefficients-are-penalized-toward-numbers-other-than, you could tell yes, though with some altered prompts it might again become impossible to tell. Easier to tell at least if answer makes sense & is correct than to tell if it's GPT or not... Which is a whole lot more useful...

Comment: @SecurityHound Yes - duh - because I said in the answer the OpenGL code was ChatGPT4, but all the rest I wrote myself (and it was verified to work & I gave the output). Yes, then you don't need an AI detector. But if I hadn't told you no one would ever have noticed & everyone would have thought it was a perfect answer & SO has explicitly asked not to take any action towards suspected use of GPT... Are you proud of that useless bit of moderation?

Comment: @TomWenseleers - Your original question that was deleted which you resubmitted then complained about, I quickly saw as being generated by OpenAI, but I said or did nothing at the time because I am on strike obviously

Comment: @SecurityHound It's literally only the OpenGL+SDL code part that was ChatGPT4 generated & even that with some edits. The rest of the answer I wrote myself. So technically impossible to tell apart, because the code would look exactly the same if I would have written it myself. The same than if I had picked up an SDL / OpenGL book. And I mentioned that for that small bit of the answer I had used ChatGPT - that gave it away. This answer you can tell it's GPT though https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76925/ridge-regression-in-r-where-coefficients-are-penalized-toward-numbers-other-than

Comment: My guess it's just a bad moment to post any questions on this policy, given the ongoing strike. Though it's also just 10% of the moderators I hear that are on strike. And they still seem to find the time to close this question, so they are not completely on strike... I imagine that very vocal 10% of the moderators massively biases any voting on this. A representative voting among the whole SO community would give a completely different result.

Comment: Hum, about the "10%" you mention, an [Update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425100/3799241) about the Strike was posted a few days ago (4) and it said: "*As of the time of writing, 113 out of 538 total Stack Exchange network moderators have signed the open strike letter, a percentage of 21%, and this number continues to grow.*" No Info though about 'SO' only, would be interesting to know the proportion for the 26(?) 'SO'-Mods...

Comment: GPT-4 *sounds* promising. I think Stack Overflow (the company) should provide free access to it, at least for a limited period, so we can evaluate it. For me, while there has been some successes, almost all responses about [QMK](https://docs.qmk.fm/#/faq_general?id=what-is-qmk) have been all made up or completely wrong (ChatGPT 3.5?).

Comment: @PeterMortensen I feel that all these people commenting here haven't even tried ChatGPT4 to be honest. I posted some representative examples here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387575/examples-of-chatgpt-being-right-and-wrong-on-stack-exchange/390348#390348. QMK would be a really specialised thing to ask about of course... Would many users or moderators know much about that either?

Comment: @PeterMortensen ChatGPT4 gives a good summary if you ask "Do you know what the QMK Environment is?".

Comment: @Tom Wenseleers: I am not talking about trivial questions. I tried to use it throughout the process of commissioning a commercial QMK-based keyboard for daily heavy use, including keyboard macros (I have previously repurposed an [AEKII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Extended_Keyboard) to use QMK) as the search engines results were mostly useless. For instance, the obvious first question is where the PgUp/PgDn went (using modifier keys for this) on 96% (surely, other QMK users must have had this problem and proposed a workaround). That is just ***an example*** (and should ***only***

Comment: @PeterMortensen Oh don't know - this is what ChatGPT4 replies to that exact question the way you phrased it. Does this make a little sense? But could be you need to ask the question in a somewhat better, clearer way https://www.dropbox.com/s/fx73t83bkrcaz8t/QMK.png?dl=1

Comment: cont' - be treated as such). The point is ChatGPT was almost completely useless to me for that particular realm, using many, many prompts for many, many problems. The only win was that it found that [Via actually works outside Google Chrome](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2023/06/12/via-a-mechanical-qmk-keyboard-configuration-works-just-fine-without-google-chrome/) (this is very well hidden by the official Via home page (incl. very misleading error messages) and its documentation): *"VIA Configurator is a desktop app that talks to your VIA-enabled keyboard"*

Comment: @Tom Wenseleers: I knew the risk and that is exactly why I wrote it was an *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***example*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I didn't succeed.

Comment: @PeterMortensen For these sorts of questions it often helps if you first paste in part of the manual or something. E.g. for my rdyncall / nara R package question I gave it an example demo so it could see some of the syntax, as those packages are only available on github & not in his training set.

Comment: @PeterMortensen But in general I also don't find it difficult to tell if the answer you get out of it makes sense or not (if it's within your subject domain). And computer code is easy enough to test...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254121/discussion-between-tom-wenseleers-and-peter-mortensen).

Answer (score 31):

> responsible users employ AI as a tool, not as a substitute for critical thinking and verification.

Please come up with guidelines to get rid of the many irresponsible users then.

> Users must still ask the right questions

As history has proven again and again, users don't know how to.

The average asker needs guidance from experienced people who have to ask several comments back-and-forth to obtain the actual criteria of a satisfying answer, all the while the GPT-users just paste the question and GPT's answer which may or may not cover a single use case and provide code that might fix the problem in the question but leave many others.

Comment: Maybe your view is based more on seeing ChatGPT3.5 produced code, not ChatGPT4? As for guidelines on getting rid of irresponsible use: a good reward system to upvote or downvote good & bad answers would already help a lot. And I would suggest to still ban users engaging in users that post large numbers of unverified answers... Just not the ones that use it responsibly.

Comment: GPT4 doesn't magically fix all the issues 3.5 has. It's really not that much better. It still suffers from many of the limitations ___any___ language model has.

Comment: @Cerbrus Not my experience. GPT3 & ChatGPT3.5 could not come up with working code for that OpenGL+SDL+rdyncall example. ChatGPT4 gave working code in just 2 prompt... And that noncentered ridge regression answer was spot on. And these are no exceptions, that's my all round experience.

Comment: Tom, just because a novice axe thrower managed to hit the bullzai once, doesn't mean he'll hit hit every time. Sure, you got a good output. ___It still generates a lot of crap___. One good example isn't enough! It needs to be ___consistent___! It's not.

Comment: @Cerbrus OK so I followed your advice and posted a new question on this and now it got closed. So I give up folks. If this is supposed to be democracy & reasonable debate I am out of here. I might take another look in 10 years or so, if and when SO has got its act together...

Comment: You didn't follow my advice. You wrote a long rambling post that's vague and full of irrelevant links and details. I told you to write _["A specific suggestion, with a justification and explanation."_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned/421848?noredirect=1#comment961895_421848). This is not that.

Comment: @Cerbrus I've been using ChatGPT4 nonstop for my work for months - this is not my assessment based on a couple of lucky shots... I'm saying it solves my questions way faster than I otherwise could & not allowing users to make use of it would cause the userbase of this platform to shrink massively... Plus that now the users that use AI responsible get punished, whilst the ones that don't disclose its use get away with it & get reputation for it... Do you think that's sustainable?

Comment: My stance is that LLMs are hit and miss. They're ___often___ confidentially incorrect. New users won't know why it's incorrect. If it works for you, yay for you. It's just not good enough for SE.

Comment: @TomWenseleers: The problem with your post is that it talks way to much about how cool ChatGPT is, but lacks concrete details about how the policy should be implemented. If you want to get a policy changed, that will only happen if you come up with a system that works, not with motivation why it should be changed alone.

Comment: Stating only verified answers are allowed will not work, because people will still post unverified answers on site. And then to ban those users, moderators would not only need to determine answer is AI generated, but also that it is wrong and they cannot do that because they may lack expertise in the area, and again there are not enough experts here willing to do that either. And once you open  AI gates, we will be flooded with such answers even more than we are now. The sites will simply die under load of AI crap.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I feel like all of that can be said for anything that can be posted on the site, AI or not. All this was true before chatgpt was invented. Moderators don't need to determine if any answer is generated by AI, only whether it is right or not, and if they can't do that (lack expertise in subject matter or whatever reason), this was still true even before answers could be generated by AI. Does chatgpt and similar AI make generating spam posts much easier? Absolutely possible. But just blanket banning any AI is not the way to handle this...

Comment: ...AI is just a tool to help in problem solving. What people do with the tool is important. The debate should not be which tools any user of the site is or is not allowed to use, but what the user is doing with the tool. People should be free to use whatever tool they wish to help them generate their question or answer. The onus of making sure the question/answer makes sense is then also on the user. Does someone keep uploading post after post of AI generated garbage? Then sanction him for that; the website already has tools for handling such vandalism

Comment: @user13267 Moderators cannot determine the validity of answers. They never did and it is not their job. It would require additional volunteer experts in each tech stack to do that. Again there aren't enough of those either. And yes, there are plenty poor posts on the sites. But the problem with AI posts is that they can look good on the surface, so it is harder to identify them as bad answers if you are not an expert and also no human can write that many answers without AI help.  There were people posting AI answers every few minutes.

Comment: @user13267 And the fact that experts are not capable of cleaning poor posts that are written by people, is evidence that we could not deal with AI posts either if the only metrics would be validity and correctness.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Again, not being able to recognize right/wrong answer if you're not an expert is a problem that existed before AI. I am aware moderators may not be able to determine the validity of answers. If people are posting answers every few minutes and we believe this is mainly because of AI use, there is still the work around of a waiting period between posts. I think that's how it is currently, there is a 30 minute waiting period between answers (but please don't quote me on that, I don't know the exact numbers)...

Comment: ...And if "experts are not capable of cleaning poor posts that are written by people" is a problem that already exists like you said, then such a problem is on the site regardless of the advent of AI. That's not any reason to disallow people who want to use AI responsibly. If someone wants to use a tool (which happens to be AI) to create posts, other users shouldn't be telling him he can't use the tool of his choice.

Comment: @user13267 Even 30 minutes is too short. And that is only valid for users with rep < 125. If people want AI answers they can ask AI directly. If you want to use AI, you can use it freely as long as you don't post such answers here. If you figure out solution with the help of AI and you understand the problem well, they you will be able to write the answer yourself based on your knowledge regardless of how you acquired it and you are free to do that.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Increase the waiting period or the rep threshold then. Workarounds can be come up with. I (and other normal users here) already know I can use AI (or whatever I want) freely to get help solving problems. And if I find a solution to a problem using AI, I shouldn't post it here why exactly? Just because a bunch of other users say so? If it was something SE itself wouldn't host then may be I could understand, but we're not talking about posting spam ad links or links to gambling sites here. If I find out the solution for a problem using AI (be it for my own problem or while...

Comment: ...doing research for someone else's question here) why shouldn't I post it as an answer and save the question asker some time? Isn't that the point of this SE forum? And there's no rule that says I need to be an expert on the subject matter and know the solutions already in order to answer questions asked here. People are free to do the research, find a solution, and post it if they like. And if they want to use AI to do their research that's their prerogative. It should not be any other users' business to tell someone how they should write their answers on the site

Comment: @user13267 you can use AI to do research and learn (if you are capable of distinguishing between correct and incorrect answers it can give you). You cannot use AI to write an answer for you.

Comment: @user13267 I am pretty sure that with my knowledge of around 50 Korean words, it would be pretty bad idea that I start posting answers at Korean Language site using  ChatGPT. Even thought it would probably be better at that than it is for solving programming problems.